# R: replace NA with item from vector

Tags: r, replace, missing-data, imputation

I am trying to replace some missing values in my data with the average values from a similar group.

My data looks like this:

```
   X   Y
1  x   y
2  x   y
3  NA  y
4  x   y
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
  X   Y
1  x   y
2  x   y
3  y   y
4  x   y
```

I wrote this, and it worked

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data.frame){
   if( is.na(data.frame$X[i]) == TRUE){
       data.frame$X[i] <- data.frame$Y[i]
   }
  }
```

But my data.frame is almost half a million lines long, and the for/if statements are pretty slow. What I want is something like

```
is.na(data.frame$X) <- data.frame$Y
```

But this gets a mismatched size error. It seems like there should be a command that does this, but I cannot find it here on SO or on the R help list. Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside - it's probably not good to use `data.frame` as your variable name, since in some contexts that masks the `data.frame()` function.

Comment: In what context? It's not really a problem.

Comment: As @hadley said, this isn't really a problem. I assume the Y column does not contain all of the same value... Like he said, we need context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ifelse` is your friend.

Using Dirk's dataset

```
df <- within(df, X <- ifelse(is.na(X), Y, X))
```

Comment: Care to compare speeds of your and Dirk's answer?

Comment: I didn't clock either method, but they both execute immediately (unlike the several minutes it took with my original code). I think I prefer this method simply because it uses one line of code instead of two.

Answer (score 9):

Just vectorise it -- the boolean index test is one expression, and you can use that in the assignment too.

Setting up the data:

```
R> df <- data.frame(X=c("x", "x", NA, "x"), Y=rep("y",4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
R> df
     X Y
1    x y
2    x y
3 <NA> y
4    x y
```

And then proceed by computing an index of where to replace, and replace:

```
R> ind <- which( is.na( df$X ) )
R> df[ind, "X"] <- df[ind, "Y"]
```

which yields the desired outcome:

```
R> df
  X Y
1 x y
2 x y
3 y y
4 x y
R>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `which`?  Is numerical indexing faster / less error prone than logical?

Comment: I prefer numeric indices (here a single '3') rather than a boolean of length N.

Comment: @Joshua: I've found that numerical indexing can indeed be much faster than logical, if the number of TRUE cases is small relative to the total number of elements.

Comment: Which is redundant here. I guess it all depends on whether you prefer Boolean algebra or set theory.

Comment: Shorter is better, and makes it easier to check interim results.  Awaiting `whch2` with my breath held ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using dplyr or tidyverse, you can use the [coalesce](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) function to do exactly this.

````r
> df <- data.frame(X=c("x", "x", NA, "x"), Y=rep("y",4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> df %>% mutate(X = coalesce(X, Y))
  X Y
1 x y
2 x y
3 y y
4 x y```
````

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment, yet, but while vectorizing some code where strings aka characters were involved the above seemd to not work. The reason being explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/invalid-factor-level-na-generated). If characters are involved  `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` is not enough because R might already have created factors out of characters. One needs to ensure that the data also becomes a character vector again, e.g.,  `data.frame(X=as.character(c("x", "x", NA, "x")), Y=as.character(rep("y",4)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`