# How do I replace NA values with zeros in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I have a data frame and some columns have `NA` values.

How do I replace these `NA` values with zeroes?

Comment: small modification of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279089/replace-all-na-into-false-in-columns-in-r (which I found by searching "[r] replace NA with zero") ...

Comment: @psychonomics what is the difference between your comment and top answer?

Comment: @svp - maybe nothing?  I cannot see my comment.  Is it possible I deleted it and you can still view?

Answer (score 1160, accepted):

See my comment in @gsk3 answer. A simple example:

```
> m <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
> d <- as.data.frame(m)
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   4  3 NA  3  7  6  6 10  6   5
2   9  8  9  5 10 NA  2  1  7   2
3   1  1  6  3  6 NA  1  4  1   6
4  NA  4 NA  7 10  2 NA  4  1   8
5   1  2  4 NA  2  6  2  6  7   4
6  NA  3 NA NA 10  2  1 10  8   4
7   4  4  9 10  9  8  9  4 10  NA
8   5  8  3  2  1  4  5  9  4   7
9   3  9 10  1  9  9 10  5  3   3
10  4  2  2  5 NA  9  7  2  5   5

> d[is.na(d)] <- 0

> d
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   4  3  0  3  7  6  6 10  6   5
2   9  8  9  5 10  0  2  1  7   2
3   1  1  6  3  6  0  1  4  1   6
4   0  4  0  7 10  2  0  4  1   8
5   1  2  4  0  2  6  2  6  7   4
6   0  3  0  0 10  2  1 10  8   4
7   4  4  9 10  9  8  9  4 10   0
8   5  8  3  2  1  4  5  9  4   7
9   3  9 10  1  9  9 10  5  3   3
10  4  2  2  5  0  9  7  2  5   5
```

There's no need to apply `apply`. =)

**EDIT**

You should also take a look at `norm` package. It has a lot of nice features for missing data analysis. =)

Comment: I already tried this code yesterday before you post it and not worked. Because this I posted the question. But I tried know and worked perfectly. I think I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição: if you tried something already, it's helpful to share that information when you ask the question; it helps to narrow down where the problem may be.

Comment: d[is.na(d)] <- 0 does not make sense to me. It seems backwards?  How does R process this statement?

Comment: @user798719 - "<-" is R's assignment operator, and can be read as: do something on the right hand side and then assign it to the location/name on the left. In this case, we aren't really "doing" anything - just making zeroes.  The left side is saying: look at the d object, inside the d object (the square brackets), find all the elements that return TRUE (is.na(d) returns a logical for each element). Once they are found, replace them ("assign them") with the value 0. These leaves all of the non-NAs as they were, and only replaces the ones with missingness.

Comment: so is.na() is vectorized thats why you passed it a whole vector?

Comment: And... if you have a data frame and only want to apply the replacement to specific nurmeric vectors (leaving say... strings with NA): `df[19:28][is.na(df[19:28])] <- 0`

Comment: Let's say instead of NA, inf was what you wanted to update to 0. How would you do that?  Notice that is.infinite(d) causes Error in is.infinite(d) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

Comment: Works on columns too, you don't need to use the whole frame.

Answer (score 477):

The dplyr hybridized options are now around 30% faster than the Base R subset reassigns. On a 100M datapoint dataframe `mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0))` runs a half a second faster than the base R `d[is.na(d)] <- 0` option. What one wants to avoid specifically is using an `ifelse()` or an `if_else()`. (The complete 600 trial analysis ran to over 4.5 hours mostly due to including these approaches.) Please see benchmark analyses below for the complete results.

If you are struggling with massive dataframes, `data.table` is the fastest option of all: 40% faster than the standard *Base R* approach. It also modifies the data in place, effectively allowing you to work with nearly twice as much of the data at once.

---

#### A clustering of other helpful tidyverse replacement approaches

***Locationally:***

- *index* `mutate_at(c(5:10), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`
- *direct reference* `mutate_at(vars(var5:var10), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`
- *fixed match* `mutate_at(vars(contains("1")), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`

- or in place of `contains()`, try `ends_with()`,`starts_with()`

- *pattern match* `mutate_at(vars(matches("\\d{2}")), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`

***Conditionally:***
(change just single type and leave other types alone.)

- *integers* `mutate_if(is.integer, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`
- *numbers*  `mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`
- *strings*  `mutate_if(is.character, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`

---

##The Complete Analysis -
*Updated for dplyr 0.8.0: functions use purrr format **`~`** symbols: replacing deprecated `funs()` arguments.*

#### Approaches tested:

```
# Base R: 
baseR.sbst.rssgn   <- function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x }
baseR.replace      <- function(x) { replace(x, is.na(x), 0) }
baseR.for          <- function(x) { for(j in 1:ncol(x))
    x[[j]][is.na(x[[j]])] = 0 }

# tidyverse
## dplyr
dplyr_if_else      <- function(x) { mutate_all(x, ~if_else(is.na(.), 0, .)) }
dplyr_coalesce     <- function(x) { mutate_all(x, ~coalesce(., 0)) }

## tidyr
tidyr_replace_na   <- function(x) { replace_na(x, as.list(setNames(rep(0, 10), as.list(c(paste0("var", 1:10)))))) }

## hybrid 
hybrd.ifelse     <- function(x) { mutate_all(x, ~ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)) }
hybrd.replace_na <- function(x) { mutate_all(x, ~replace_na(., 0)) }
hybrd.replace    <- function(x) { mutate_all(x, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) }
hybrd.rplc_at.idx<- function(x) { mutate_at(x, c(1:10), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) }
hybrd.rplc_at.nse<- function(x) { mutate_at(x, vars(var1:var10), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) }
hybrd.rplc_at.stw<- function(x) { mutate_at(x, vars(starts_with("var")), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) }
hybrd.rplc_at.ctn<- function(x) { mutate_at(x, vars(contains("var")), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) }
hybrd.rplc_at.mtc<- function(x) { mutate_at(x, vars(matches("\\d+")), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) }
hybrd.rplc_if    <- function(x) { mutate_if(x, is.numeric, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) }

# data.table   
library(data.table)
DT.for.set.nms   <- function(x) { for (j in names(x))
    set(x,which(is.na(x[[j]])),j,0) }
DT.for.set.sqln  <- function(x) { for (j in seq_len(ncol(x)))
    set(x,which(is.na(x[[j]])),j,0) }
DT.nafill        <- function(x) { nafill(df, fill=0)}
DT.setnafill     <- function(x) { setnafill(df, fill=0)}
```

#### The code for this analysis:

```
library(microbenchmark)
# 20% NA filled dataframe of 10 Million rows and 10 columns
set.seed(42) # to recreate the exact dataframe
dfN <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, as.numeric(1:4)), 1e7*10, replace = TRUE),
                            dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:10)), 
                            ncol = 10))
# Running 600 trials with each replacement method 
# (the functions are excecuted locally - so that the original dataframe remains unmodified in all cases)
perf_results <- microbenchmark(
    hybrd.ifelse     = hybrd.ifelse(copy(dfN)),
    dplyr_if_else    = dplyr_if_else(copy(dfN)),
    hybrd.replace_na = hybrd.replace_na(copy(dfN)),
    baseR.sbst.rssgn = baseR.sbst.rssgn(copy(dfN)),
    baseR.replace    = baseR.replace(copy(dfN)),
    dplyr_coalesce   = dplyr_coalesce(copy(dfN)),
    tidyr_replace_na = tidyr_replace_na(copy(dfN)),
    hybrd.replace    = hybrd.replace(copy(dfN)),
    hybrd.rplc_at.ctn= hybrd.rplc_at.ctn(copy(dfN)),
    hybrd.rplc_at.nse= hybrd.rplc_at.nse(copy(dfN)),
    baseR.for        = baseR.for(copy(dfN)),
    hybrd.rplc_at.idx= hybrd.rplc_at.idx(copy(dfN)),
    DT.for.set.nms   = DT.for.set.nms(copy(dfN)),
    DT.for.set.sqln  = DT.for.set.sqln(copy(dfN)),
    times = 600L
)
```

#### Summary of Results

> ```
> > print(perf_results)
> Unit: milliseconds
>               expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>       hybrd.ifelse 6171.0439 6339.7046 6425.221 6407.397 6496.992 7052.851   600
>      dplyr_if_else 3737.4954 3877.0983 3953.857 3946.024 4023.301 4539.428   600
>   hybrd.replace_na 1497.8653 1706.1119 1748.464 1745.282 1789.804 2127.166   600
>   baseR.sbst.rssgn 1480.5098 1686.1581 1730.006 1728.477 1772.951 2010.215   600
>      baseR.replace 1457.4016 1681.5583 1725.481 1722.069 1766.916 2089.627   600
>     dplyr_coalesce 1227.6150 1483.3520 1524.245 1519.454 1561.488 1996.859   600
>   tidyr_replace_na 1248.3292 1473.1707 1521.889 1520.108 1570.382 1995.768   600
>      hybrd.replace  913.1865 1197.3133 1233.336 1238.747 1276.141 1438.646   600
>  hybrd.rplc_at.ctn  916.9339 1192.9885 1224.733 1227.628 1268.644 1466.085   600
>  hybrd.rplc_at.nse  919.0270 1191.0541 1228.749 1228.635 1275.103 2882.040   600
>          baseR.for  869.3169 1180.8311 1216.958 1224.407 1264.737 1459.726   600
>  hybrd.rplc_at.idx  839.8915 1189.7465 1223.326 1228.329 1266.375 1565.794   600
>     DT.for.set.nms  761.6086  915.8166 1015.457 1001.772 1106.315 1363.044   600
>    DT.for.set.sqln  787.3535  918.8733 1017.812 1002.042 1122.474 1321.860   600
> ```

#### Boxplot of Results

```
ggplot(perf_results, aes(x=expr, y=time/10^9)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    xlab('Expression') +
    ylab('Elapsed Time (Seconds)') +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1)) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image: Boxplot Comparison of Elapsed Time]

#### Color-coded Scatterplot of Trials (with y-axis on a log scale)

```
qplot(y=time/10^9, data=perf_results, colour=expr) + 
    labs(y = "log10 Scaled Elapsed Time per Trial (secs)", x = "Trial Number") +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.75, 7.5)) +
    scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0.75, 0.875, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, seq(2, 7.5)))
```

[image: Scatterplot of All Trial Times]

#### A note on the other high performers

When the datasets get larger, *Tidyr*''s `replace_na` had historically pulled out in front. With the current collection of 100M data points to run through, it performs almost exactly as well as a *Base R* For Loop. I am curious to see what happens for different sized dataframes.

Additional examples for the `mutate` and `summarize` `_at` and `_all` function variants can be found here: https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/summarise_all.html
Additionally, I found helpful demonstrations and collections of examples here: https://blog.exploratory.io/dplyr-0-5-is-awesome-heres-why-be095fd4eb8a

#### Attributions and Appreciations

With special thanks to:

- [Tyler Rinker](https://www.r-bloggers.com/microbenchmarking-with-r/) and [Akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41530071/5088194) for demonstrating microbenchmark.
- [alexis_laz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633258/5088194) for working on helping me understand the use of `local()`, and (with Frank's patient help, too) the role that silent coercion plays in speeding up many of these approaches.
- ArthurYip for the poke to add the newer `coalesce()` function in and update the analysis.
- Gregor for the nudge to figure out the `data.table` functions well enough to finally include them in the lineup.
- *Base R* For loop: [*alexis_laz*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633258/5088194)
- *data.table* For Loops: [*Matt_Dowle*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/5088194)
- Roman for explaining what `is.numeric()` really tests.

*(Of course, please reach over and give them upvotes, too if you find those approaches useful.)*

***Note on my use of Numerics:***  If you do have a pure integer dataset, all of your functions will run faster. Please see [alexiz_laz's work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633258/5088194) for more information. IRL, I can't recall encountering a data set containing more than 10-15% integers, so I am running these tests on fully numeric dataframes.

***Hardware Used***
3.9 GHz CPU with 24 GB RAM

Comment: @Frank - Thank you for finding that discrepancy.  The references are all cleaned up and the results have been entirely rerun on a single machine and reposted.

Comment: Ok thanks. Also, I think `df1[j][is.na(df1[j])] = 0` is wrong, should be `df1[[j]][is.na(df1[[j]])] = 0`

Comment: Oh now I see you've written it twice, differently in each benchmark. Anyway, `forLp_Sbst` doesn't seem like a way anyone should consider approaching it vs `forLp_smplfSbst`

Comment: @Frank - Is there a better way to have the for loop leave all the numerics as numerics?

Comment: I don't follow. What are they converted to with the current code? `z <- c(1,2,3); z[2] <- 0L; str(z)`  is still num.

Comment: Your answer above with the double brackets simplifies the class as much as possible (using integer coercion where possible). This added transform of numerics to integers is what I am trying to remove in the single bracket non simplifying loop in the numeric group tests: in an effort to compare replacement methods on an equal footing. (Ultimately finding that For loops really only work faster in integer situations.)

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure nothing can transform a numeric to an integer. If you have a simple example, maybe bring it to the R chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: For a more complete explanation, please refer to the link at the end of the post- Alexis_Laz does a much better job of explaining the integer and double coercion rules at play there.http://stackoverflow.com/a/41633258/5088194

Comment: Yes, I had a look. You are misunderstanding how coercion works. Alexis refers to coercion from integer to numeric, not the other way around.

Comment: @Frank - you are right. I don't understand what is going on with the For loops. I will take them out. Thank you for pointing out the coding errors.

Comment: I'm curious to learn why you encapsulated all expressions in `local()` when benchmarking?

Comment: @UweBlock - great question: it allowed me to do the subsetting left assign operation with all functions working on exactly the same dataframe. Since I had to wrap the local around that function, then in the name of science [One job, you had one job!] I wrapped it around all of them so that the playing field was unequivocally level. For more info - please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604711/discrepancies-in-benchmark-and-processing-time-results
I had trimmed down the rather longwinded previous answer - but that part of the discussion would be good to add back in. Thank you!

Comment: I tested mut_all_ coalesce and it had times comparable to mut_all_replace.       dfL %>% mutate_all(funs(coalesce(., 0L)))

Comment: @ArthurYip - I've added the `coalesce()` option in and rerun all the times. Thank you for the nudge to update.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor for the reference. In the process of updating indeed. I will get the DT ones added in too. (I've been curious to see how `data.table` works and this would be a good start.)

Comment: @Gregor - I had gotten the DT functions all wrapped and included in but then discovered that one of the amazing powers of `data.table` was skewing the whole analysis. I had `firewalled` the original dataframe by wrapping all actions in `function()`s or in `local()` or both so that every action would be performed on the same unmodified dataframe. Unfortunately, in this case, `data.table` set and `:= ` modify in place. I will have to find a way to rebuild the 50M line dataframe each time if I want to test those functions with the others. That will take a bit more processing (& coding) time...

Comment: @Gregor - results are in. DT approaches are definitely the fastest. I am curious to now, see how everything performs on different dataframe sizes. Thanks again for the nudge and please let me know if I left anything else out. (Also, thought it would be good to mention that I did test the less speedier DT options offered on that thread, and only included in these two which were faster than the other non DT options.)

Comment: @leerssej you might want to add another solution, which should be fastest AFAIK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504573/2490497 instead of `local` use `copy` before modifying DT in place

Comment: @jangorecki: the install_github pre-release is failing to update in my data.table package. Looking forward to adding this in when the `nafill` are officially released.

Comment: i looked at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976331/use-of-tilde-in-r-programming-language and still can't figure out what the `tilde` is doing in this script... it works fine with it but removing it causes and error... why is that?

Comment: Tidyverse is using a formula to build anonymous functions - it is throughout tidyverse now but I found the brief explanation in this [purrr doc](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) to be most helpful. It is also more thoroughly mentioned in R for Datascience [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#shortcuts)

Comment: @leerssej Small nitpick: `is.numeric` does not necessarily mean _double_. Manual: «is.numeric is a more general test of an object being interpretable as numbers».

Comment: Update for dplyr 1.0.2 that removes the `mutate_at` and `mutate_all`: `function(x) { mutate(across(x, ~replace_na(., 0))) }`

Comment: `across` also supports inline anonymous functions which might provide a slight performance boost over `~` which has to be converted to a function: `mutate(across(everything(), \(x) replace_na(x, 0)))`.

Answer (score 162):

For a single vector:

```
x <- c(1,2,NA,4,5)
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
```

For a data.frame, make a function out of the above, then `apply` it to the columns.

Please provide a reproducible example next time as detailed here:

[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `is.na` is generic function, and has methods for objects of `data.frame` class. so this one will also work on `data.frame`s!

Comment: When I ran `methods(is.na)` for the first time, I was like _whaaa?!?_. I love when stuff like that happen! =)

Comment: Suppose you have a data frame named df instead of a single vector and you just want to replace missing observations in a single column named X3.  You can do so with this line: df$X3[is.na(df$X3)] <- 0

Comment: Suppose you only want to replace NA with 0 in columns 4-6 of a data frame named my.df.  You can use: my.df[,4:6][is.na(my.df[,4:6])] <- 0

Comment: how come you pass 'x' to is.na(x)  is there a way to tell which library routines in R are vectorized?

Answer (score 98):

dplyr example:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(myCol1 = if_else(is.na(myCol1), 0, myCol1))
```

**Note:** This works per selected column, if we need to do this for all column, see *@reidjax*'s answer using [mutate_each](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334491/680068).

Answer (score 72):

It is also possible to use `tidyr::replace_na`.

```
    library(tidyr)
    df <- df %>% mutate_all(funs(replace_na(.,0)))
```

Edit (dplyr > 1.0.0):

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), .fns = ~replace_na(.,0)))
```

Comment: `mutate_*` verbs are now superseded by `across()`

Comment: I am curious as to why I need wo wrap the `replace(is.na(.), 0)` function inside `mutate()`.Why not feed it directly to the pipe?

Comment: `mutate` enables to create or replace variables.

Comment: As of `dplyr 1.1.0` this is how you should write the replacement
`mutate(data, across(.cols = everything(), \(x) replace_na(x, 0)))`

Answer (score 71):

If we are trying to replace `NA`s when exporting, for example when writing to csv, then we can use:

```
  write.csv(data, "data.csv", na = "0")
```

Answer (score 60):

I know the question is already answered, but doing it this way might be more useful to some:

Define this function:

```
na.zero <- function (x) {
    x[is.na(x)] <- 0
    return(x)
}
```

Now whenever you need to convert NA's in a vector to zero's you can do:

```
na.zero(some.vector)
```

Comment: `return(x)` is not needed, `x` is sufficient.

Answer (score 33):

More general approach of using `replace()` in matrix or vector to replace `NA` to `0`

For example:

```
> x <- c(1,2,NA,NA,1,1)
> x1 <- replace(x,is.na(x),0)
> x1
[1] 1 2 0 0 1 1
```

This is also an alternative to using `ifelse()` in `dplyr`

```
df = data.frame(col = c(1,2,NA,NA,1,1))
df <- df %>%
   mutate(col = replace(col,is.na(col),0))
```

Comment: My column was a factor so I had to add my replacement value
`levels(A$x) <- append(levels(A$x), "notAnswered")
A$x <- replace(A$x,which(is.na(A$x)),"notAnswered")`

Comment: `which` isn't needed here, you can use `x1 <- replace(x,is.na(x),1)`.

Comment: I tried many ways proposed in this thread to replace `NA` to `0` in just one specific column in a large data frame and this function `replace()` worked the most effectively while also the most simply.

Answer (score 33):

With `dplyr` 0.5.0, you can use `coalesce` function which can be easily integrated into `%>%` pipeline by doing `coalesce(vec, 0)`. This replaces all NAs in `vec` with 0:

Say we have a data frame with `NA`s:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(v = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, 8))

df
#    v
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
# 4 NA
# 5  5
# 6  6
# 7  8

df %>% mutate(v = coalesce(v, 0))
#   v
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3
# 4 0
# 5 5
# 6 6
# 7 8
```

Comment: I tested coalesce and it performs about the same as replace. the coalesce command is the simplest so far!

Comment: it would be useful if you would present how to apply that on all columns of 2+ columns tibble.

Comment: `mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ coalesce(.x, 0)))`

Answer (score 29):

To replace all NAs in a dataframe you can use:

`df %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)`

Comment: this is not a new solution

Comment: But it's a fast, easy and simple answer. I like it.

Answer (score 14):

Would've commented on @ianmunoz's post but I don't have enough reputation.  You can combine `dplyr`'s `mutate_each` and `replace` to take care of the `NA` to `0` replacement.  Using the dataframe from @aL3xa's answer...

```
> m <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
> d <- as.data.frame(m)
> d

    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   4  8  1  9  6  9 NA  8  9   8
2   8  3  6  8  2  1 NA NA  6   3
3   6  6  3 NA  2 NA NA  5  7   7
4  10  6  1  1  7  9  1 10  3  10
5  10  6  7 10 10  3  2  5  4   6
6   2  4  1  5  7 NA NA  8  4   4
7   7  2  3  1  4 10 NA  8  7   7
8   9  5  8 10  5  3  5  8  3   2
9   9  1  8  7  6  5 NA NA  6   7
10  6 10  8  7  1  1  2  2  5   7

> d %>% mutate_each( funs_( interp( ~replace(., is.na(.),0) ) ) )

    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   4  8  1  9  6  9  0  8  9   8
2   8  3  6  8  2  1  0  0  6   3
3   6  6  3  0  2  0  0  5  7   7
4  10  6  1  1  7  9  1 10  3  10
5  10  6  7 10 10  3  2  5  4   6
6   2  4  1  5  7  0  0  8  4   4
7   7  2  3  1  4 10  0  8  7   7
8   9  5  8 10  5  3  5  8  3   2
9   9  1  8  7  6  5  0  0  6   7
10  6 10  8  7  1  1  2  2  5   7
```

We're using standard evaluation (SE) here which is why we need the underscore on "`funs_`."  We also use `lazyeval`'s `interp`/`~` and the `.` references "everything we are working with", i.e. the data frame.  Now there are zeros!

Answer (score 13):

Another example using **imputeTS** package:

```
library(imputeTS)
na.replace(yourDataframe, 0)
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to replace NAs in factor variables, this might be useful:

```
n <- length(levels(data.vector))+1

data.vector <- as.numeric(data.vector)
data.vector[is.na(data.vector)] <- n
data.vector <- as.factor(data.vector)
levels(data.vector) <- c("level1","level2",...,"leveln", "NAlevel")
```

It transforms a factor-vector into a numeric vector and adds another artifical numeric factor level, which is then transformed back to a factor-vector with one extra "NA-level" of your choice.

Answer (score 12):

Dedicated functions, `nafill` and `setnafill`, for that purpose is in `data.table`.
Whenever available, they distribute columns to be computed on multiple threads.

```r
library(data.table)

ans_df <- nafill(df, fill=0)

# or even faster, in-place
setnafill(df, fill=0)
```

Answer (score 9):

#### dplyr >= 1.0.0

In newer versions of `dplyr`:

> across() supersedes the family of "scoped variants" like summarise_at(), summarise_if(), and summarise_all().

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(LETTERS[1:3], NA), b = c(NA, 1:3))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(anyNA), ~ replace_na(., 0)))

  a b
1 A 0
2 B 1
3 C 2
4 0 3
```

This code will coerce `0` to be character in the first column. To replace `NA` based on column type you can use a purrr-like formula in `where`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~ anyNA(.) & is.character(.)), ~ replace_na(., "0")))
```

Answer (score 9):

No need to use any library.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,3,5,NA))

df$a[is.na(df$a)] <- 0

df
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `replace()`

For example:

```
> x <- c(-1,0,1,0,NA,0,1,1)
> x1 <- replace(x,5,1)
> x1
[1] -1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1

> x1 <- replace(x,5,mean(x,na.rm=T))
> x1
[1] -1.00  0.00  1.00  0.00  0.29  0.00 1.00  1.00
```

Comment: True, but only practical when you know the index of `NA`s in your vector. It's fine for small vectors as in your example.

Comment: @dardisco  `x1 <- replace(x,is.na(x),1)` will work without explicitly listing the index values.

Answer (score 7):

The `cleaner` package has an `na_replace()` generic, that *at default* replaces numeric values with zeroes, logicals with `FALSE`, dates with today, etc.:

```
library(dplyr)
library(cleaner)

starwars %>% na_replace()
na_replace(starwars)
```

It even supports vectorised replacements:

```
mtcars[1:6, c("mpg", "hp")] <- NA
na_replace(mtcars, mpg, hp, replacement = c(999, 123))
```

Documentation: https://msberends.github.io/cleaner/reference/na_replace.html

Answer (score 5):

Another `dplyr` pipe compatible option with `tidyr`method `replace_na` that works for several columns:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

m <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
d <- as.data.frame(m)

myList <- setNames(lapply(vector("list", ncol(d)), function(x) x <- 0), names(d))

df <- d %>% replace_na(myList)
```

You can easily restrict to e.g. numeric columns:

```
d$str <- c("string", NA)

myList <- myList[sapply(d, is.numeric)]

df <- d %>% replace_na(myList)
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple function extracted from [Datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/writing-functions-in-r) could help:

```
replace_missings <- function(x, replacement) {
  is_miss <- is.na(x)
  x[is_miss] <- replacement

  message(sum(is_miss), " missings replaced by the value ", replacement)
  x
}
```

Then

```
replace_missings(df, replacement = 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to write it is with `if_na` from `hablar`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, 8))

df %>% 
  mutate(a = if_na(a, 0))
```

which returns:

```
      a
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     0
5     5
6     6
7     8
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `collapse::replace_NA`. By default, `replace_NA` replaces NAs with 0s.

```r
library(collapse)
replace_NA(df)
```

For only some columns:

```r
replace_NA(df, cols = c("V1", "V5")) 
#Alternatively, one can use a function, indices or a logical vector to select the columns
```

---

It's also faster than any other answer (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585689/13460602) for a comparison):

```r
set.seed(42) # to recreate the exact dataframe
dfN <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, as.numeric(1:4)), 1e7*10, replace = TRUE),
                            dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:10)), 
                            ncol = 10))

microbenchmark(collapse = replace_NA(dfN))

# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min      lq     mean  median       uq     max neval
#  collapse 508.9198 621.405 751.3413 714.835 859.5437 1298.69   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace is.na & NULL in data frame.

1. data frame with colums

A$name[is.na(A$name)]<-0

OR

A$name[is.na(A$name)]<-"NA"

2. with all data frame

df[is.na(df)]<-0

3. with replace na with blank in data frame

df[is.na(df)]<-""

4. replace NULL to NA

df[is.null(df)] <- NA

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign a new name after changing the NAs in a specific column in this case column V3, use you can do also like this

```
my.data.frame$the.new.column.name <- ifelse(is.na(my.data.frame$V3),0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wan to add a next solution which using a popular [`Hmisc` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html).

```r
library(Hmisc)
data(airquality)
# imputing with 0 - all columns
# although my favorite one for simple imputations is Hmisc::impute(x, "random")
> dd <- data.frame(Map(function(x) Hmisc::impute(x, 0), airquality))
> str(dd[[1]])
 'impute' Named num [1:153] 41 36 12 18 0 28 23 19 8 0 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:153] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 - attr(*, "imputed")= int [1:37] 5 10 25 26 27 32 33 34 35 36 ...
> dd[[1]][1:10]
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
 41  36  12  18  0*  28  23  19   8  0*
```

There could be seen that all imputations metadata are allocated as attributes. Thus it could be used later.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a new solution, but I like to write inline lambdas that handle things that I can't quite get packages to do. In this case,

```
df %>%
   (function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; return(x) })
```

Because R does not ever "pass by object" like you might see in Python, this solution does not modify the original variable `df`, and so will do quite the same as most of the other solutions, but with much less need for intricate knowledge of particular packages.

Note the parens around the function definition! Though it seems a bit redundant to me, since the function definition is surrounded in curly braces, it is required that inline functions are defined within parens for `magrittr`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more flexible solution. It works no matter how large your data frame is, or zero is indicated by `0` or `zero` or whatsoever.

```
library(dplyr) # make sure dplyr ver is >= 1.00

df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), na_if, 0)) # if 0 is indicated by `zero` then replace `0` with `zero`
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `sapply` to replace all `NA` with zeros. Here is some reproducible code (data from @aL3xa):

```r
set.seed(7) # for reproducibility
m <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
d <- as.data.frame(m)
d
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#> 1   9  7  5  5  7  7  4  6  6   7
#> 2   2  5 10  7  8  9  8  8  1   8
#> 3   6  7  4 10  4  9  6  8 NA  10
#> 4   1 10  3  7  5  7  7  7 NA   8
#> 5   9  9 10 NA  7 10  1  5 NA   5
#> 6   5  2  5 10  8  1  1  5 10   3
#> 7   7  3  9  3  1  6  7  3  1  10
#> 8   7  7  6  8  4  4  5 NA  8   7
#> 9   2  1  1  2  7  5  9 10  9   3
#> 10  7  5  3  4  9  2  7  6 NA   5
d[sapply(d, \(x) is.na(x))] <- 0
d
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#> 1   9  7  5  5  7  7  4  6  6   7
#> 2   2  5 10  7  8  9  8  8  1   8
#> 3   6  7  4 10  4  9  6  8  0  10
#> 4   1 10  3  7  5  7  7  7  0   8
#> 5   9  9 10  0  7 10  1  5  0   5
#> 6   5  2  5 10  8  1  1  5 10   3
#> 7   7  3  9  3  1  6  7  3  1  10
#> 8   7  7  6  8  4  4  5  0  8   7
#> 9   2  1  1  2  7  5  9 10  9   3
#> 10  7  5  3  4  9  2  7  6  0   5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Please note**: Since R 4.1.0 you can use `\(x)` instead of `function(x)`.

Answer (score -1):

in data.frame it is not necessary to create a new column by mutate.

```
library(tidyverse)    
k <- c(1,2,80,NA,NA,51)
j <- c(NA,NA,3,31,12,NA)
        
df <- data.frame(k,j)%>%
   replace_na(list(j=0))#convert only column j, for example
```

result

```
k   j
1   0           
2   0           
80  3           
NA  31          
NA  12          
51  0
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this personally and works fine:

```
players_wd$APPROVED_WD[is.na(players_wd$APPROVED_WD)] <- 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.