# How to replace NaN values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have a Pandas Dataframe as below:

```
      itm Date                  Amount 
67    420 2012-09-30 00:00:00   65211
68    421 2012-09-09 00:00:00   29424
69    421 2012-09-16 00:00:00   29877
70    421 2012-09-23 00:00:00   30990
71    421 2012-09-30 00:00:00   61303
72    485 2012-09-09 00:00:00   71781
73    485 2012-09-16 00:00:00     NaN
74    485 2012-09-23 00:00:00   11072
75    485 2012-09-30 00:00:00  113702
76    489 2012-09-09 00:00:00   64731
77    489 2012-09-16 00:00:00     NaN
```

When I try to apply a function to the Amount column, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I have tried applying a function using `math.isnan`, pandas' `.replace` method, `.sparse` data attribute from pandas 0.9, if `NaN == NaN` statement in a function; I have also looked at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-r); none of them works.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 986, accepted):

I believe `DataFrame.fillna()` will do this for you.

Link to Docs for [a dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and for [a Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Example:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
          0         1
0       NaN       NaN
1 -0.494375  0.570994
2       NaN       NaN
3  1.876360 -0.229738
4       NaN       NaN

In [8]: df.fillna(0)
Out[8]: 
          0         1
0  0.000000  0.000000
1 -0.494375  0.570994
2  0.000000  0.000000
3  1.876360 -0.229738
4  0.000000  0.000000
```

To fill the NaNs in only one column, select just that column. in this case I'm using inplace=True to actually change the contents of df.

```
In [12]: df[1].fillna(0, inplace=True)
Out[12]: 
0    0.000000
1    0.570994
2    0.000000
3   -0.229738
4    0.000000
Name: 1

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
          0         1
0       NaN  0.000000
1 -0.494375  0.570994
2       NaN  0.000000
3  1.876360 -0.229738
4       NaN  0.000000
```

**EDIT:**

To avoid a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, use the built in column-specific functionality:

```
df.fillna({1:0}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `df[1]` is a view rather than a copy of the original DF? Obviously, if there's a rare situation where it's a copy, it would cause a super-troublesome bug. Is there a clear statement on that in pandas documentation?

Comment: @max See this, might address your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy

Comment: Thanks. Is my understanding correct that in that answer an "indexer that sets" is the outermost indexing operation (executed just before the assignment. So any assignment that only uses a single indexer is guaranteed to be safe, making your code safe?

Comment: @max I do not know what you mean by "safe"... but in any case, this seems off topic here. :) Probably best to comment on that other question, or post a new question.

Comment: More info for fillna() can be found here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: Why is this not working for me? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452095/how-to-fillna-with-value-0

Comment: What's the equivalent for a list?

Comment: the last example throws a SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: @Farrukh Faizy's answer is really the way `fillna()` is designed to handle specific columns. Perhaps replace the second solution with his as your answer will always be on top?? :)

Answer (score 195):

It is not guaranteed that the slicing returns a view or a copy. You can do

```
df['column'] = df['column'].fillna(value)
```

Comment: Just discovered the "inplace=True" problem.  This answer avoids the issue and I think is the cleanest solution presented.

Answer (score 67):

You could use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to change `NaN` to `0`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# for column
df['column'] = df['column'].replace(np.nan, 0)

# for whole dataframe
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)

# inplace
df.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Will it only replace `NaN` ? or it will also replace value where `NA` or `NaN` like `df.fillna(0)`? I am looking for solution which only replace value where there is `NaN` and not `NA`

Comment: @ShyamBhimani it should replace only `NaN` i.e. values where `np.isnan` is True

Answer (score 31):

The below code worked for me.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('somefile.txt')

df = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: One liner

`df = pandas.read_csv('somefile.txt').fillna(0)`

Answer (score 29):

I just wanted to provide a bit of an update/special case since it looks like people still come here. If you're using a multi-index or otherwise using an index-slicer the inplace=True option may not be enough to update the slice you've chosen. For example in a 2x2 level multi-index this will not change any values (as of pandas 0.15):

```py
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,mask_1],idx[mask_2,:]].fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
```

The "problem" is that the chaining breaks the fillna ability to update the original dataframe. I put "problem" in quotes because there are good reasons for the design decisions that led to not interpreting through these chains in certain situations. Also, this is a complex example (though I really ran into it), but the same may apply to fewer levels of indexes depending on how you slice.

The solution is DataFrame.update:

```py
df.update(df.loc[idx[:,mask_1],idx[[mask_2],:]].fillna(value=0))
```

It's one line, reads reasonably well (sort of) and eliminates any unnecessary messing with intermediate variables or loops while allowing you to apply fillna to any multi-level slice you like!

If anybody can find places this doesn't work please post in the comments, I've been messing with it and looking at the source and it seems to solve at least my multi-index slice problems.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use dictionaries to fill NaN values of the specific columns in the DataFrame rather to fill all the DF with some oneValue.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
df.fillna( {
        'column1': 'Write your values here',
        'column2': 'Write your values here',
        'column3': 'Write your values here',
        'column4': 'Write your values here',
        .
        .
        .
        'column-n': 'Write your values here'} , inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

**Easy way to fill the missing values:-**

**filling** **string columns:** when string columns have missing values and NaN values.

```
df['string column name'].fillna(df['string column name'].mode().values[0], inplace = True)
```

**filling** **numeric columns:** when the numeric columns have missing values and NaN values.

```
df['numeric column name'].fillna(df['numeric column name'].mean(), inplace = True)
```

**filling NaN with zero:**

```
df['column name'].fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 7):

To replace na values in pandas

```
df['column_name'].fillna(value_to_be_replaced,inplace=True)
```

if `inplace = False`, instead of updating the df (dataframe) it will return the modified values.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Considering the particular column `Amount` in the above table is of integer type. The following would be a solution :

```
df['Amount'] = df.Amount.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Similarly, you can fill it with various data types like `float`, `str` and so on.

In particular, I would consider datatype to compare various values of the same column.

Answer (score 5):

**To replace nan in different columns with different ways:**

```
   replacement= {'column_A': 0, 'column_B': -999, 'column_C': -99999}
   df.fillna(value=replacement)
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me, but no one's mentioned it. could there be something wrong with it?

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].isnull(), 'column_name'] = 0
```

Comment: only this worked for me :D , df.fillna(0) didn't work (changed nothing with no error)

Answer (score 3):

There are two options available primarily; in case of imputation or filling of missing values *NaN / np.nan* with only numerical replacements (across column(s):

`df['Amount'].fillna(value=None, method= ,axis=1,)` is sufficient:

From the Documentation:

value : scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame
    Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a
    dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for
    each index (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame). (values not
    in the dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled). This value cannot
    be a list.

Which means 'strings' or 'constants' are no longer permissable to be imputed.

For more specialized imputations use **SimpleImputer()**:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
si = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', missing_values=np.nan, fill_value='Replacement_Value')
df[['Col-1', 'Col-2']] = si.fit_transform(X=df[['C-1', 'C-2']])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fill NaN for a specific column  you can use loc:

```
d1 = {"Col1" : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     "fruits": ['Avocado', 'Banana', 'NaN']}
d1= pd.DataFrame(d1)

output:

Col1    fruits
0   A   Avocado
1   B   Banana
2   C   NaN


d1.loc[ d1.Col1=='C', 'fruits' ] =  'Carrot'


output:

Col1    fruits
0   A   Avocado
1   B   Banana
2   C   Carrot
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also worth mention and explain
the parameters configuration of fillna()
like Method, Axis, Limit, etc.

From the documentation we have:

```
Series.fillna(value=None, method=None, axis=None, 
                 inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None)
Fill NA/NaN values using the specified method.
```

Parameters

```
value [scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame] Value to use to 
 fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a dict/Series/DataFrame 
 of values specifying which value to use for each index 
 (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame). Values not in 
 the dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled. This 
 value cannot be a list.

method [{‘backfill’, ‘bfill’, ‘pad’, ‘ffill’, None}, 
 default None] Method to use for filling holes in 
 reindexed Series pad / ffill: propagate last valid 
 observation forward to next valid backfill / bfill: 
 use next valid observation to fill gap axis 
 [{0 or ‘index’}] Axis along which to fill missing values.

inplace [bool, default False] If True, fill 
 in-place. Note: this will modify any other views
 on this object (e.g., a no-copy slice for a 
 column in a DataFrame).

limit [int,defaultNone] If method is specified, 
 this is the maximum number of consecutive NaN 
 values to forward/backward fill. In other words, 
 if there is a gap with more than this number of 
 consecutive NaNs, it will only be partially filled. 
 If method is not specified, this is the maximum 
 number of entries along the entire axis where NaNs
 will be filled. Must be greater than 0 if not None.

downcast [dict, default is None] A dict of item->dtype 
 of what to downcast if possible, or the string ‘infer’ 
 which will try to downcast to an appropriate equal 
 type (e.g. float64 to int64 if possible).
```

Ok. Let's start with the `method=` Parameter this
have forward fill (ffill) and backward fill(bfill)
ffill is doing copying forward the previous
non missing value.

e.g. :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':np.nan, 'c3':200}, {'c1':np.nan,'c2':110, 'c3':210}, {'c1':12,'c2':np.nan, 'c3':220},{'c1':12,'c2':130, 'c3':np.nan},{'c1':12,'c2':np.nan, 'c3':240}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

  c1       c2      c3
0   10.0     NaN      200.0
1   NaN   110.0 210.0
2   12.0     NaN      220.0
3   12.0     130.0 NaN
4   12.0     NaN      240.0
```

Forward fill:

```
df.fillna(method="ffill")

    c1     c2      c3
0   10.0      NaN 200.0
1   10.0    110.0   210.0
2   12.0    110.0   220.0
3   12.0    130.0   220.0
4   12.0    130.0   240.0
```

Backward fill:

```
df.fillna(method="bfill")

    c1      c2     c3
0   10.0    110.0   200.0
1   12.0    110.0   210.0
2   12.0    130.0   220.0
3   12.0    130.0   240.0
4   12.0      NaN   240.0
```

The Axis Parameter help us to choose the direction of the fill:

**Fill directions:**

ffill:

```
Axis = 1 
Method = 'ffill'
----------->
  direction 

df.fillna(method="ffill", axis=1)

       c1   c2      c3
0   10.0     10.0   200.0
1    NaN    110.0   210.0
2   12.0     12.0   220.0
3   12.0    130.0   130.0
4   12.0    12.0    240.0

Axis = 0 # by default 
Method = 'ffill'
|
|       # direction 
|
V
e.g: # This is the ffill default
df.fillna(method="ffill", axis=0)

    c1     c2      c3
0   10.0      NaN   200.0
1   10.0    110.0   210.0
2   12.0    110.0   220.0
3   12.0    130.0   220.0
4   12.0    130.0   240.0
```

bfill:

```
axis= 0
method = 'bfill'
^
|
|
|
df.fillna(method="bfill", axis=0)

    c1     c2      c3
0   10.0    110.0   200.0
1   12.0    110.0   210.0
2   12.0    130.0   220.0
3   12.0    130.0   240.0
4   12.0      NaN   240.0

axis = 1
method = 'bfill'
<-----------
df.fillna(method="bfill", axis=1)
        c1     c2       c3
0    10.0   200.0   200.0
1   110.0   110.0   210.0
2    12.0   220.0   220.0
3    12.0   130.0     NaN
4    12.0   240.0   240.0

# alias:
#  'fill' == 'pad' 
#   bfill == backfill
```

limit parameter:

```
df
    c1     c2      c3
0   10.0      NaN   200.0
1    NaN    110.0   210.0
2   12.0      NaN   220.0
3   12.0    130.0     NaN
4   12.0      NaN   240.0
```

Only replace the first NaN element across columns:

```
df.fillna(value = 'Unavailable', limit=1)
            c1           c2          c3
0          10.0 Unavailable       200.0
1   Unavailable       110.0       210.0
2          12.0         NaN       220.0
3          12.0       130.0 Unavailable
4          12.0         NaN       240.0

df.fillna(value = 'Unavailable', limit=2)

           c1            c2          c3
0          10.0 Unavailable       200.0
1   Unavailable       110.0       210.0
2          12.0 Unavailable       220.0
3          12.0       130.0 Unavailable
4          12.0         NaN       240.0
```

downcast parameter:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   c1      4 non-null      float64
 1   c2      2 non-null      float64
 2   c3      4 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 248.0 bytes

df.fillna(method="ffill",downcast='infer').info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   c1      5 non-null      int64  
 1   c2      4 non-null      float64
 2   c3      5 non-null      int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 248.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to replace NaN is via `mask()`/`where()` methods. They are similar methods where `mask` replaces values that satisfy the condition whereas `where` replaces values that do not satisfy the condition. So to use, we just have to filter the NaN values and replace them with the desired value.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, float('nan'), float('nan')], 'b': [float('nan'), 'a', 'b']})

df = df.where(df.notna(), 10)                 # for the entire dataframe
df['a'] = df['a'].where(df['a'].notna(), 10)  # for a single column
```

The advantage of this method is that we can conditionally replace NaN values with it. The following is an example where NaN values in `df` are replaced by `10` if the condition `cond` is satisfied.

```py
cond = pd.DataFrame({'a': [True, True, False], 'b':[False, True, True]})
df = df.mask(df.isna() & cond, 10)
```

Under the hood, `fillna()` calls `where()` ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8b7fd0d7ea13d83adac001fd95d2fa372e301d0b/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py#L1539)) which in turn calls `numpy.where()` if the dataframe is small and `numexpr.evaluate` if it's large ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8b7fd0d7ea13d83adac001fd95d2fa372e301d0b/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py#L259)). So `fillna`/`mask`/`where` are essentially the same method for the purposes of replacing NaN values. On the other hand, `replace()` (another method given on this page) is a `numpy.putmask` operation ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8b7fd0d7ea13d83adac001fd95d2fa372e301d0b/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py#L797)). Because `numexpr` is a faster than `numpy` for large arrays, for very large dataframes, `replace` may be outperformed by the other methods.

---

On a tangential note, it's common for a dataframe to have a literal string `'NaN'` instead of an actual NaN value. To make sure that a dataframe indeed has NaN values, check with `df.isna().any()`. If it returns False, when it should contain NaN, then you probably have `'NaN'` strings, in which case, use `replace` to convert them into NaN or, even better, replace with the value you're meant to replace it with. For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'NaN']})
df = df.replace('NaN', 'c')
```