# Trying to select data from all columns that start with string from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, null, dataframe

I'm trying to select all columns that start with a certain string and then fill all the null values in with a new value. What I'm doing now just turns all the column headers into a list instead though.

```
lifestyle_var = [col for col in list(df) if col.startswith('lifestyle')]

df[lifestyle_var].fillna(1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem meanwhile: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10342

You can use this command: `df.loc[:,lifestyle_var] = df.loc[:,lifestyle_var].fillna(1)`

This problem happens because you're trying to fill the copy of the dataframe, not the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df.update(df[lifestyle_var].fillna(1))
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-can-i-replace-all-the-nan-values-with-zeros-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-datafra).

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame([ [ 1, 2, np.nan ], [ np.nan, np.nan, 6] ], columns=   ['a1', 'b', 'a2'])
vars = [ col for col in list(data) if col.startswith('a')]
data.update(data[vars].fillna(value=1))
```

Comment: This ends up not working as it doesn't treat lifestyle_var as the column headers for whatever reason.

Comment: @Ron can you try the example and tell me the result? i.e. print the values for 'vars' and 'data'

Comment: Worked for your example: `>>> print vars
['a1', 'a2']
>>> print data
   a1   b  a2
0   1   2   1
1   1 NaN   6` Now got it to work, I had kept the argument inplace=True when I initially tested it.