# How to replace all non-NaN entries of a dataframe with 1 and all NaN with 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 71 columns and 30597 rows. I want to replace all non-nan entries with 1 and the nan values with 0.

Initially I tried for-loop on each value of the dataframe which was taking too much time.

Then I used **data_new=data.subtract(data)** which was meant to subtract all the values of the dataframe to itself so that I can make all the non-null values 0. 
But an error occurred as the dataframe had multiple string entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace all the NaN values with Zero's in a column of a pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-can-i-replace-all-the-nan-values-with-zeros-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-datafra)

Answer (score 58):

You can take the return value of `df.notnull()`, which is `False` where the DataFrame contains `NaN` and `True` otherwise and cast it to integer, giving you `0` where the DataFrame is `NaN` and `1` otherwise:

```
newdf = df.notnull().astype('int')
```

If you really want to write into your original DataFrame, this will work:

```
df.loc[~df.isnull()] = 1  # not nan
df.loc[df.isnull()] = 0   # nan
```

Comment: Sorry, please dont copy my answer. I think your version is equal by mine, so I think it is not necessary.

Comment: Did you notice that I posted this answer before you?

Comment: Yes, but not with `notnull()`. Your answer was with `~isnull()`. And it is equal, so I think your solution is so good as mine.

Comment: You're right that both our answers achieve the same in pretty much the same way. I tried to improve my answer by removing an unneccessary double inversion.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. But unfortunately if some answer is better, I think it is bad copy it. You can upvote it -;) [I  do it only twice in SO, because I aware about be low in ordering :(

Answer (score 25):

Use [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) with casting boolean to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
print ((df.notnull()).astype('int'))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, 4, np.nan], 'b': [1,np.nan,3]})
print (df)
     a    b
0  NaN  1.0
1  4.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0

print (df.notnull())
       a      b
0  False   True
1   True  False
2  False   True

print ((df.notnull()).astype('int'))
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  0
2  0  1
```

Comment: if you are interested in the inverse of this answer: `(df.isnull()).astype('int')`

Answer (score 5):

I'd advise making a new column rather than just replacing. You can always delete the previous column if necessary but its always helpful to have a source for a column populated via an operation on another.

e.g. if df['col1'] is the existing column

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: 1 if not pd.isnull(x) else np.nan)
```

where col2 is the new column. Should also work if col2 has string entries.

Answer (score 4):

I do a lot of data analysis and am interested in finding new/faster methods of carrying out operations.  I had never come across jezrael's method, so I was curious to compare it with my usual method (i.e. replace by indexing).  NOTE: This is not an answer to the OP's question, rather it is an illustration of the efficiency of jezrael's method.  Since this is NOT an answer I will remove this post if people do not find it useful (and after being downvoted into oblivion!).  Just leave a comment if you think I should remove it.

I created a moderately sized dataframe and did multiple replacements using both the df.notnull().astype(int) method and simple indexing (how I would normally do this).  It turns out that the latter is slower by approximately five times.  Just an fyi for anyone doing larger-scale replacements.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


# create dataframe with randomly place NaN's
data = np.ones( (1e2,1e2) )
data.ravel()[np.random.choice(data.size,data.size/10,replace=False)] = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

trials = np.arange(100)


d1 = dt.datetime.now()

for r in trials:
    new_df = df.notnull().astype(int)

print( (dt.datetime.now()-d1).total_seconds()/trials.size )


# create a dummy copy of df.  I use a dummy copy here to prevent biasing the 
# time trial with dataframe copies/creations within the upcoming loop
df_dummy = df.copy()

d1 = dt.datetime.now()

for r in trials:
    df_dummy[df.isnull()] = 0
    df_dummy[df.isnull()==False] = 1

print( (dt.datetime.now()-d1).total_seconds()/trials.size )
```

This yields times of 0.142 s and 0.685 s respectively.  It is clear who the winner is.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method [`.fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on DataFrames which does what you need. For example:

```
df = df.fillna(0)  # Replace all NaN values with zero, returning the modified DataFrame
```

or

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)   # Replace all NaN values with zero, updating the DataFrame directly
```

Comment: This only partially answers the question, the question is about replacing both NaN and non-NaN.

Answer (score 2):

for fmarc 's answer:

```
df.loc[~df.isnull()] = 1  # not nan
df.loc[df.isnull()] = 0   # nan
```

The code above does not work for me, and the below works.

```
df[~df.isnull()] = 1  # not nan
df[df.isnull()] = 0   # nan
```

With the pandas 0.25.3

And if you want to just change values in specific columns, you may need to create a temp dataframe and assign it to the columns of the original dataframe:

```
change_col = ['a', 'b']
tmp = df[change_col]
tmp[tmp.isnull()]='xxx'
df[change_col]=tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
df.notnull().mul(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i will give a suggestion to take a particular column and if the rows in that column is NaN replace it by 0 or values are there in that column replace it as 1

this below line will change your column to 0

```
df.YourColumnName.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Now Rest of the Not Nan Part will be Replace by 1 by below code

```
df["YourColumnName"]=df["YourColumnName"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x!=0 else 0)
```

Same Can Be applied to the total dataframe by not defining the column Name

Comment: What about values at 0 at the beginning?

Comment: @B.Go that will change the NaN values to 0 to check 0 on second line.i tried to Check with the  second line as if 'NaN'  but that was an error.You can't,To check NaN like that you need to use Numpy .So this was the easy way for me.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are two steps - substitute all not NAN values and then substitute all NAN values.

1. `dataframe.where(~dataframe.notna(), 1)` - this line will replace all not nan values to 1.
2. `dataframe.fillna(0)` - this line will replace all NANs to 0

Side note: if you take a look at pandas documentation, `.where` replaces all values, that are `False` - this is important thing. That is why we use inversion to create a mask `~dataframe.notna()`, by which `.where()` will replace values

Answer (score 0):

Use: `df.fillna(0)`

to fill NaN with 0.