# Updating existing dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which has the structure as follows

```
code      value
1          red
2          blue 
3          yellow
1
4          
4          pink
2          blue
```

so basically i want to update the value column so that the blank rows are filled with values from other rows. So I know the code 4 refers to value pink, I want it to be updated in all the rows where that value is not present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace all the NaN values with Zero's in a column of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-can-i-replace-all-the-nan-values-with-zeros-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-datafra)

Answer (score 4):

Using `groupby` and `ffill` and `bfill`

```
df.groupby('code').value.ffill().bfill()
```

```
0       red
1      blue
2    yellow
3       red
4      pink
5      pink
6      blue
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: One thing .. df.groupby('code').value.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())

Comment: Nvm ignore that last comment, I think you may be right, I need to test this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `first` value of the given `code` group

```
In [379]: df.groupby('code')['value'].transform('first')
Out[379]:
0       red
1      blue
2    yellow
3       red
4      pink
5      pink
6      blue
Name: value, dtype: object
```

---

To assign back

```
In [380]: df.assign(value=df.groupby('code')['value'].transform('first'))
Out[380]:
   code   value
0     1     red
1     2    blue
2     3  yellow
3     1     red
4     4    pink
5     4    pink
6     2    blue
```

Or

```
df['value'] = df.groupby('code')['value'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a series of your `code`-`value` pairs, and use that to `map`:

```
my_map = df[df['value'].notnull()].set_index('code')['value'].drop_duplicates()

df['value'] = df['code'].map(my_map)

>>> df
   code   value
0     1     red
1     2    blue
2     3  yellow
3     1     red
4     4    pink
5     4    pink
6     2    blue
```

Just to see what is happening, you are passing the following series to `map`:

```
>>> my_map
code
1       red
2      blue
3    yellow
4      pink
Name: value, dtype: object
```

So it says: "Where you find `1`, give the value `red`, where you find `2`, give `blue`..."

Comment: `df.dropna().set_index('code')['value']` would  do too.

Comment: `df.dropna().set_index('code')['value'].drop_duplicates()`, because you still have to make sure there are no duplicate indices when you pass to `map`

Comment: @sacul you could use `to_dict` to remove the duplicates and map using the dictionary

Comment: I am still getting 2 rows for one of the code value pair, where one value is blank and other has the correct value. Is there a way to check if that field anything apart from Null, may be blank space? This is in the my_map

Comment: you can try starting with `df.replace({'':pd.np.nan, ' ':pd.np.nan}, inplace=True)` to get rid of those cases from the start

Answer (score 2):

You can `sort_values`, `ffill` and then `sort_index`. The last step may not be necessary if order is not important. If it is, then the double sort may be unreasonably expensive.

```
df = df.sort_values(['code', 'value']).ffill().sort_index()

print(df)

   code   value
0     1     red
1     2    blue
2     3  yellow
3     1     red
4     4    pink
5     4    pink
6     2    blue
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `reindex`

```
df.dropna().drop_duplicates('code').set_index('code').reindex(df.code).reset_index()
Out[410]: 
   code   value
0     1     red
1     2    blue
2     3  yellow
3     1     red
4     4    pink
5     4    pink
6     2    blue
```

Comment: this works, but with one problem. The first value of code 4 is null, so the result has all the value column for row with code 4 update to null.