# Python 3 replacing nan values

Tags: python-3.x, nan

I am trying to replace some nan values in a few columns using a calculation from other columns.
ie.

```
nancolumn = column1.value + column2.value
```

My first attempt didn't work, ie there is still nan values

```
indecies = list(list(map(tuple, np.where(np.isnan(df['nancolumn']))))[0])
newValue = df.iloc[indecies]['column1'] + df.iloc[indecies ]['column2']
df.iloc[indecies]['nancolumn'] = newValue
```

I then found a specific index that i wanted to replace, 1805, and tried just replacing this data point value with 1.0. The result is still a nan

```
df.iloc[1805]['nancolumn'] = 1.0
```

I tried using fillna(), and isnan()

```
df[np.isnan(df)]=1
```

I get this error for the isnan() attempt:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
df.iloc[1805]['nancolumn'].dtype
dtype('float64')
```

I know im missing something simple, but i can't figure it out.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-can-i-replace-all-the-nan-values-with-zeros-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-datafra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that its best to use reference the column first and then the index, like below

```
df['nancolumn'].iloc[1805] = 1.0
```

Although, i still don't really understand the difference. If any one has a explenation, that would be helpful.