# Python: Replace all column by output of reg

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In my dataset, i have a feature (called `Size`) like this one:

```
import pandas as pd


dit={"Size" : ["0","0","5mm","12-15","3-10"] }
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dit)
```

This feature specifies a size in a range (with minimum and maximum) or by a specific number.

Now, i wish to replace the values by the ***Maximum*** of each range.

So, in my example the output should be

```
dit={"Size" : ["0","0","5mm","15mm","10mm"] }
```

This is what i have tried:

```
import re
dt = re.split("-",dt.loc[:,"Size"])
```

But, it complains with:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

and this is makes sense because the type of `dt.loc[:," Size (in mm)"]` is:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

My question is, ***how can i simply update this column without a loop?***

Comment: Could you add a sample of `dt`?

Comment: @NelsonGon i updated my question. it was missed. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression might return the desired output, which I have assumed `mm` is not desired:

```
import pandas as pd

dit={"Size" : ["0","0","5mm","12-15mm","3mm-10mm"] }
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dit)

dt['max_size']=dt["Size"].str.replace(r"^.*?(\d+)\D*$",r"\1")

print(dt)
```

#### Output

```
       Size max_size
0         0        0
1         0        0
2       5mm        5
3   12-15mm       15
4  3mm-10mm       10
```

Comment: if i have `Nan` instead of `Zeros`, then what can i do?

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
import pandas as pd
import re

dit={"Size" : ["0","0","5mm","12-15","3-10"] }
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dit)
rx = r'(\d+)(?:mm)?-(\d+)(?:mm)?'
dt['Size']=dt['Size'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(rx, lambda z: str(max(int(z.group(1)), int(z.group(2)))) + "mm", x))
```

Output:

```
>>> dt
   Size
0     0
1     0
2   5mm
3  15mm
4  10mm
```

The regex matches

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?:mm)?` - an optional `mm` char sequence
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(?:mm)?` -  - an optional `mm` char sequence.

The `str(max(int(z.group(1)), int(z.group(2)))) + "mm"` keeps the biggest value of the numbers in two groups and appends `mm` at the end.

Comment: if i have `Nan` instead of `Zeros`, then what can i do?

Comment: @Jeff Add `.fillna(0)`. See [How can I replace all the NaN values with Zero's in a column of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735).

Comment: Typically, you'd use `str.replace` for string/regex replacement: `dt['Size'].str.replace(rx, lambda z: z.group(1) if int(z.group(1))  > int(z.group(2)) else z.group(2))`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use this simple regex to replace everything that is   before `-`:

```
  import pandas as pd
   dit={"Size" : ["0","0","5mm","12-15mm","3mm-10mm"] }
   dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dit)
   dt["max_size"] = dt["Size"].str.replace(".*\-","")
   dt
       Size max_size
0         0        0
1         0        0
2       5mm      5mm
3   12-15mm     15mm
4  3mm-10mm     10mm
```

If you don't need the `mm` at the end, then:

```
dt["max_size"] = dt["Size"].str.replace(r".*-|mm$", "")
dt
       Size max_size
0         0        0
1         0        0
2       5mm        5
3   12-15mm       15
4  3mm-10mm       10
```

Comment: Thanks, but i donot need `mm` in output

Comment: Ok, I'll edit. Just followed this: `So, in my example the output should be  dit={"Size" : ["0","0","5mm","15mm","10mm"] }`

Answer (score 1):

With simple *mask* and `Series.apply` function:

```
In [172]: m = df['Size'].str.contains('-?\d+mm$')                                                                                               

In [173]: df.loc[m, 'Size'] = df.loc[m, 'Size'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[-1])                                                              

In [174]: df                                                                                                                                   
Out[174]: 
   Size
0     0
1     0
2   5mm
3  15mm
4  10mm
```

---

`'-?\d+mm$'` pattern details:

- `-?` - matches optional `-` char
- `\d+mm$` - matches one or more digit `\d` followed by `mm` suffix at the end of the string `$`

Comment: Thanks, but i donot need mm in output

Comment: @Jeff, then why did you write *my example the output should be* `["0","0","5mm","15mm","10mm"]` in your question???