# Convert (NA) object to zero

Tags: pandas

I've seen all the posts on dropping all the "Na"s in a dataset with `df.dropna` but I've found that all of these methods only apply to strings. If I have an object that is "(NA)" how would I convert these to zeros? Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You don't want to _drop_, since that means removing data. You want to substitute your data. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-can-i-replace-all-the-nan-values-with-zeros-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-datafram) answer your question? If no, why? If possible, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60889982/edit) your question to add a sample of the data you want to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function fillna

```
df['test'] = df.test.fillna(0)
```

This is will fill the NA values of column "test" with zeros