# Why does putting "NANO" inside pandas .fillna() do?

Tags: pandas, data-science

```
df_train[catcols] = df_train[catcols].fillna("NANO")
df_test[catcols[:-2]] = df_test[catcols[:-2]].fillna("NANO")
```

Comment: All `NaN` values in the selected columns willbe replaced with `NANO`. Does this answer your question? [How to replace NaN values by Zeroes in a column of a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-to-replace-nan-values-by-zeroes-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: yeah understood DavidErickson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fillna is a method in pandas series and dataframe. It replaces NA/NAN values in a dataframe.

Syntax :

```
df.fillna(value=None, method=None, axis=None, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None, **kwargs)
```

In this case

```
df_train[catcols] = df_train[catcols].fillna("NANO")
df_test[catcols[:-2]] = df_test[catcols[:-2]].fillna("NANO")
```

'NANO' string is replaces where a NONE value is found in the dataframe.

For example:

if your dataframe df is :

```
Index   Name
1      Jacob
2      Andrew
3       NONE
4       NONE
5      Steve

df['Name'].fillna('Aagam')

Index   Name
1      Jacob
2      Andrew
3      Aagam
4      Aagam
5      Steve
```

to learn more visit [Pandas.dataframe.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)