# Python: replace nulls with 0

Tags: python, for-loop, null, nan, isnull

What is the best way to replace all the null "NaN" values in a Python dataframe with the value 0?

Also, is it possible to do this with a for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace NaN values by Zeroes in a column of a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-to-replace-nan-values-by-zeroes-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: ```df.fillna(0)```. And Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure to read the guideline on how to post questions. Also, make sure to have made an honest attempt at solving the issue yourself.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use

```
df.fillna(0)
```