# Replacing each Null value in dataframe with a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace each instance of null value by a different value each time. The values are in a list CB.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 0, 'b': np.NaN, 'c':np.NaN, 'd': np.NaN}, index = [0])
CB = [1, 2, 3]
print(df)
```

Result is:

```
   a   b   c   d
0  0 NaN NaN NaN
```

Expected output:

```
   a   b   c   d
0  0   1   2   3
```

Comment: Why is that the expected result? You did nothing with `CB`

Comment: Will the size of the list always match the amount of `nan`s?

Comment: i think you need `df.isnull().cumsum(axis=1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace NaN values by Zeroes in a column of a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-to-replace-nan-values-by-zeroes-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: What if `a` has null. Is that to be ignored? What if only `b` has null. Can you add those as inputs in your question pls

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
In [4422]: df[df.columns[df.isna().any()]] = CB

In [4423]: df
Out[4423]: 
   a    b    c    d
0  0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

#### EDIT:

Consider below `df`:

```
In [4621]: df
Out[4621]: 
   a    b    c    d
0  0  4.0  5.0  6.0
1  0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If you want to change `NaN` values in only `last row`, do this:

Get the column names which have `NaN` in last row:

```
In [4623]: cols = df.columns[df.iloc[-1].isna()]
In [4631]: cols
Out[4631]: Index(['b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

Now, set the values for these `cols` from list `CB`:

```
In [4631]: CB = [1, 2, 3]

In [4628]: df.loc[df.index[-1], cols] = CB

In [4629]: df
Out[4629]: 
   a    b    c    d
0  0  4.0  5.0  6.0
1  0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: What if I had many rows in my DataFrame and I only wanted to change the final row which contains NaNs?

Comment: @YoussefElSayed then update your question to reflect that with a proper [mre]

Comment: @YoussefElSayed I've updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a dataframe (making it a bit bigger that the original question)

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""
   a   b   c   d
0  0   4   5   6
1  0 NaN NaN NaN
"""), delim_whitespace=True)
```

then we can do the following

```
dfs = df.stack(dropna = False)
dfs[dfs.isna()] = CB
df = dfs.unstack()
df
```

produces

```
    a   b   c   d
0   0.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
1   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

Here we unwrap the `df` into a timeseries using `stack()`, filter to NaNs, replace with `CB`, and fold back into the original shape