# Replacing Missing Values with 0

Tags: python, pandas, replace, currency

I have a large list of data, but one column I am filtering by (sales) has some missing data. It seems that I am getting an error with the function I made to convert dollar abbreviations (110M to 110,000,000) when here are missing values in the list. The error I get is "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable." So I am trying to replace all missing values in this column with 0 so that when I run the function, it will iterate through every value in the column and if I filter so that sales > certain value, it will just filter those rows out.

Here an example of this:

```
def num_conv(sales_list):
    m = {'M': 6, 'B': 9}
    return ([(float(i[:-1]) * 10 ** m[i[-1]]) for i in sales_list])

sales = ['100M', '100B', None, '200M']

sales = sales.replace(np.nan, 0)
sales = num_conv(sales)
print(sales)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace NaN values by Zeroes in a column of a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-to-replace-nan-values-by-zeroes-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: The error is actually in `num_conv` itself. If `sales_list` is a list as shown in your example, then calling `for i in sales_list` makes `i` a single value, which must be either a list or a `str` for `i[-1]` to work. If you'll try to replace all missing values with zero (an `int`), your code will fail on the `TypeError` shown above.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan, if `i` is a string, then `i[-1]` is perfectly fine.

Comment: BTW, `None` is not the same as NaN: NaN is a floating-point value, while `None` is `NoneType`.

Comment: @ForceBru My bad, fixed, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this by modifying your list comprehension:

```
def num_conv(sales_list):
    m = {'M': 6, 'B': 9}
    return ([(float(i[:-1]) * 10 ** m[i[-1]]) if i else 0 for i in sales_list])
```

---

```
sales = ['100M', '100B', None, '200M']
sales = num_conv(sales)
print(sales)
```

And the output will be

```
[100000000.0, 100000000000.0, 0, 200000000.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do simple.

```
# python (simple)
def num_conv(sales_list):
    m = {'M': 6, 'B': 9}
    return ([(float(i[:-1]) * 10 ** m[i[-1]]) for i in sales_list])

sales = ['100M', '100B', None, '200M']
sales_li = []
for sale in sales:
    if sale:
        sales_li.append(sale)
    else:
        sales_li.append('0M')

sales = num_conv(sales_li)
print(sales)
```