# Why does Ifelse fail to replace NAs?

Tags: r, dataset, na, if-statement

I have a dataset where one column contains entries of `yes`, `no`, and `NA`. I want to replace any `NA` with `1`, and replace any non-`NA` entry with `0`. `Ifelse` replaces the non-`NA` entries with `0`, but does NOT replace the `NA` entries with `1`. I need to use the `is.na()` command for that. Why does `is.na()` work where `ifelse` does not?

I define a reproducible example below that starts with the column defined as a factor since that's how I got the data.

```
    q <-as.factor(c(NA, "yes",  "no",   "yes", NA))

    ## Does not work
    q <- ifelse(q == "NA", 1, 0)
q    
### Returns: [1] NA  0  0  0 NA

    ## Does not work
    q[q == "NA"] <- 1
q    
### Returns: [1] NA  0  0  0 NA    

    ## This works
    q[is.na(q)] <- 1
q
### Returns: [1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

Some other entries exist, but they do not seem to have this precise problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166616/1364839 -- This answer shows that `is.na()` works but not why `ifelse` fails.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `ifelse`. You are doing two completely different logical comparisons. The string "NA" has nothing to do with `NA`.

Comment: Read `?base::Logic` and `?NA`.

Comment: How do I directly refer to `NA` in ifelse?

Comment: Read `?base::Logic` and `?NA`. `ifelse( is.na(q) , 1, 0)`

Comment: `>     q <- ifelse(q == NA, 1, 0)` ...Outputs, `[1] NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: You cannot do any comparisons with NA value, any comparison with NA will result in NA. Try this: `c(NA=="yes",NA==NA,NA=="NA",NA==1,is.na(NA))`

Comment: @DTRM I updated the comment - I am in need of coffee, look at `?is.na`,  in fact, instead of `ifelse` just do `as.integer( is.na( q ) )` - UPDATE - oh, that is what you are doing. So what is this question?!!

Comment: Stackoverflow etiquette question: now that you two cleared this up for me, should I click "Answer Your Question," refer to you two, and then write up the main points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need `ifelse()` here, not least because if you don't know the value of something (which is what `NA` indicates!) how can you compare its value with something else?

```
> NA == NA ## yes, even NA can't be compared with itself
[1] NA
```

Instead, use `is.na()` to identify whether something is `NA` or not. `is.na()` returns `TRUE` if an element is `NA` and `FALSE` otherwise. Then we can use the fact that `FALSE == 0` and `TRUE == 1` when we coerce to numeric:

```
q <-as.factor(c(NA, "yes",  "no",   "yes", NA))
q

as.numeric(is.na(q))

> as.numeric(is.na(q))
[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

If that is too much typing then

```
> is.na(q) + 0
[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

works via the same trick except `+` is doing the coercion for you.

Comment: Great thanks! Also, @SimonO101 above pointed out `ifelse( is.na(q) , 1, 0)` as yet another approach.

Comment: @DTRM Not really, if you look at the guts of `ifelse` you'll see it is overkill for something like this. More generally useful perhaps yes, but not in regard to your question.