# How do I replace <NA> values with zeros in R?

Tags: r, import

I have a data.frame and some columns have `NA` values. I want to replace the `<NA>`s with zeros. How I do this?

Actually, mydate, shown here, isn't my original data. the original is too large to show here.

```
mydata = read.spss('mydata.sav', use.value.labels = TRUE, to.data.frame = TRUE, max.value.labels = Inf, trim.factor.names = FALSE, trim_values = FALSE, reencode = "UTF-8")


> mydata
   Q_16_O3 Q_16_O4 Q_16_O5 Q_16_O6 Q_16_O7 Q_16_O8 Q_16_O9
10    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
11    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
12    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
13    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
14    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
15    Trem    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
16    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
17    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
18    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
19    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
20    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>


    str(mydata)

    'data.frame':   11 obs. of  7 variables:

    $ Q_16_O3: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA 4
 NA NA NA NA ...

    $ Q_16_O4: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA
 NA NA NA NA NA ...

    $ Q_16_O5: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA
 NA NA NA NA NA ...

    $ Q_16_O6: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA
 NA NA NA NA NA ...

    $ Q_16_O7: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA
 NA NA NA NA NA ...

    $ Q_16_O8: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA
 NA NA NA NA NA ...

    $ Q_16_O9: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA
 NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I would like to use the freq function, so I must not change its structure(mydata).

ps: My problem is `<NA>`, not  `NA`
In the `NA` case, I have a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-r/8166616#8166616).

Comment: What's the data type?  Check using `lapply(mydata,summary)` and post that into your answer.

Comment: `<NA>` is just `NA` for character vectors when displayed in a `data.frame` (via `print.data.frame`). It's still highly likely it is just a normal `NA` as it is for `data.frame(text=c("a",NA))` Did you try the other solution first?

Comment: I'd love to know: which of these cases is true?  Are your `<NA>` values really characters or NA values within factors??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For practically any data structure `X` containing numerics, use

```
X[is.na(X)] <- 0
```

Your question seems slightly discombobulated though - you have indicated that you mean `<NA>` not NA, without explaining what *type* `<NA>` is.

If it is the string `"<NA>"` you mean, then

```
X[X=="<NA>"] <- "0"
```

If you have mixed data types in your data frame, check for that too:

```
X[is.character(X) & X=="<NA>"] <- "0"
```

which is strictly more useful in the numeric case.

```
X[is.numeric(X) & is.na(X)] <- 0
```

This is a very common idiom for dealing with missing data in R, although you should also look at the parameter `na.rm = TRUE` which many functions such as `mean`, `sum`, &c. will accept.

This strategy will fail for a factor, because you cannot add new factor levels by assigning to the value of a factor.  I haven't used read.spss, but looking at the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.spss.html), I suggest you add the `use.value.labels = FALSE` argument to your call, to avoid creating factors in the first place.

In your specific case, your entire data frame is of the same type (factor).  This means it's safe to convert to a character matrix

```
> class(mydata[[1]])
"factor"
> mydataM <- as.matrix(mydata) 
> mode(mydataM)
"character"
```

Now you can replace the NA values

```
X[is.character(X) & X=="<NA>"] <- "0"
```

In the more general case where you have unwanted factor columns mixed in with other types, you need to do something a little more complex.

```
myDataM=as.data.frame(lapply(x,
  function(x)if(class(x)=="factor")as.character(x)else x))
```

Comment: It's not working... I would like to use the freq function in some column of my new data... I will improove my question!

Comment: Thanks, okay, these are factor variables.  You are correct, it won't work, because you can't add levels to a factor like this.