# Replace NA's with zero in "xts" "zoo" object in R

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'm working on a function within the quantmod package where I want to figure out how to replace the NAs with a zero, such that I don't remove the entire row if I were to use the na.omit function, because I don't want to lose the other values contained in the columns where there isn't an NA. I want the structure to remain.

I have an xts object that contains 6 columns.

1st column (row.names) that contain monthly dates from 2005-01-01 through 2010-01-01.
2nd column has Stock1 that contains stock prices and NA's
3rd column has Stock2 that contains stock prices and Na's
4th column has Stock3 that contains stock prices and Na's
5th column has Stock4 that contains stock prices and Na's
6th column has Stock5 that contains stock prices and Na's

When I execute:

```
cat("Found", sum(is.na(MY_OBJECT)), "Na's")           
NEW_OBJECT <- na.omit(MY_OBJECT) #Returns the new object where the entire row is deleted
```

Appreciate the feedback.

New code to replace the NA's with zero's without object structure being changed.

```
NEW_OBJECT <- na.fill(MY_OBJECT, fill = 0.00))
```

Comment: See `na.fill` in zoo.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck. I added the new code. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You can try the following: NEW_OBJECT[is.na(NEW_OBJECT)] <- 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace NA values with zeros in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-r)