# replace na values in full dataset using r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working on a dataset with few missing values marked as "?", I have to replace them with the most common value(mode) of that column. But, I want to write a code which runs it for the whole dataset at once.

I have gotten so far -

```
df <- read.csv("mushroom.txt", na.strings = "?",header=FALSE)
```

Now, trying to replace all the NA values in the file with the mode of that column. Please help.

Comment: I think there are a lot of similar questions, start with give a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-r) or at least provide a minimal example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to replace by the mode of a column you want to operate in a column-wise fashion via apply and use `is.na` to identify those columns that you want to replace.

```
apply(df, 2, function(x){ 
    x[is.na(x)] <- names(which.max(table(x)))
    return(x) })
```

Note that `apply` returns a `matrix`, so if you want a `data.frame` you would need to convert with `as.data.frame`

Answer (score 1):

```
replaceQuestions <- function(vector) {

  mostCommon <- names(sort(table(vector), decreasing = TRUE))[1]

  vector[vector == '?'] <- mostCommon

  vector

}

df <- apply(df, 2, replaceQuestions)
```

Not reproducible so I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but this solves the problem as I've interpreted it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it in your question, you're replacing NAs with `"?"` during your csv-reading, so I think this could help:

```
apply(df,2,function(x) gsub("\\?",names(sort(-table(x,exclude="?")))[1],x))
```

The `exclude` part is to avoid selecting the `"?"`, shall it be the most frequent value. The `\\` is to escape the special character ? to gsub.

====== **EDIT TO ADD** ======

`gsub` will convert everything to text, you'll need to make it back to numeric again:

```
a<-apply(df,2,function(x) gsub("\\?",names(sort(-table(x,exclude="?")))[1],x))
new_df<-as.data.frame(apply(a,2,as.numeric))
```

Last line will produce a new data frame

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- Mode(x[complete.cases(x)])
  x})
```

This uses the well-known Mode function on SO. Link to the function [Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for (i in ncol(dataframename){
   dataframename[i]=
   ifelse(is.na(dataframename[i]),mode(dataframename[i]),dataframename[i])
}
```