# How are results of complete.cases() and data[is.na(data)] <- 0 different?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `data` and after several computations on it, the final dataframe `df.final` has some missing values in it.

Before going ahead with further calculations on `df.final`, am I better off making all missing values zero's by

```
data[id.na(data)] <- 0
```

as mentioned here at 
 [How do I replace NA values with zeros in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-r), or would doing

```
df.final <- df.final[complete.cases(df.final), ] # considering only one's without na
```

be more beneficial?

How are the two different?

Comment: Those two are completely different. `df[is.na(df)] <- 0` just replaces all NA values in the data with zero,  while `df[complete.cases(df), ]` removes all rows in the data that contain at least one NA.  The latter is also the same as `na.omit(df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `NA` to zero, then the effect on your calculations is as if you **measured it and got zero**. So if you're measuring temperatures in July, you'll get results as if you had a few frosty days in there. Your average temperature will be lower.

If you set `na.rm=T` or use `complete.cases`, the effect is as if **that measurement never happened** (which is the case, really). So our average temperature in July would be the average only for the days we did measure.

If you only have a few isolated NA values (`sum(is.na())`) then you might want to set them all to 0 (or some other sensible value, in this example the **average temperature in July** might be good).

I would only set to zero if there were vanishingly few (so I don't really care that it's skewing my measurements) or if zero was a sensible value (for example, if we want work experience in months, `NA` might well mean "no experience").

Software is soft: if your dataset is small enough, you can try both and observe how much it affects *your* data.

Comment: thanks for the clear and concise explanation. It gives me a better perspective on how to go ahead.