# How to replace NAs with characters within a df

Tags: r

I want all NAs to be replaced with "Not Found" in a df .

i have this df

```
A    B
1    NA
2    NA
3    NA
```

How can i get that .

```
A    B
1    Not Found
2    Not Found
3    Not Found
```

Comment: It's better to leave it as `NA`s. Especially if that column is a `factor`. Other than that, a simple Google search gives all you need. Have you saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-r ?

Comment: Use this: `df$B[is.na(df$B)] <- "Not Found"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Assign "Not Found" to `df[is.na(df)]`. However, it will cause errors if some columns are factors.

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = rep(NA, 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   A  B
# 1 1 NA
# 2 2 NA
# 3 3 NA
 df[is.na(df)] <- "Not Found"
df
#   A         B
# 1 1 Not Found
# 2 2 Not Found
# 3 3 Not Found
```