# dplyr::mutate (assign na.rm =TRUE)

Tags: r, sum, dplyr, na

I have a data.frame that has 100 variables. I want to get the sum of three variables only using `mutate` (not `summarise`).

If there is NA in any of the 3 variables, I still want to get the `sum`. In order to do this using `mutate`, I replaced all `NA` values with `0` using `ifelse` then I got the `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(mod_var1 = ifelse(is.na(var1), 0, var1),
              mod_var2 = ifelse(is.na(var2), 0, var2),
              mod_var3 = ifelse(is.na(var3), 0, var3),
              sum = (mod_var1+mod_var2+mod_var3))
```

Is there any better (shorter) way to do this?

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
var1    var2    var3
4   5   NA
2   NA  3
1   2   4
NA  3   5
3   NA  2
1   1   5"), header =T)
```

Comment: `replace(df, is.na(df), 0) %>% mutate(sum = var1 + var2 + var3)`

Comment: @RichScriven
Your answer is great. However, as I mentioned in the question I have a data.frame that have 100 variables and your answer will replace NA in all 100 variables with zero (not only var1,var2, and var3) which I don't want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `+`

```
df %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)), var1:var3) %>% 
     mutate(Sum = Reduce(`+`, .))      
#   var1 var2 var3 Sum
#1    4    5    0   9
#2    2    0    3   5
#3    1    2    4   7
#4    0    3    5   8
#5    3    0    2   5
#6    1    1    5   7
```

---

Or with `rowSums`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(Sum = rowSums(.[names(.)[1:3]], na.rm = TRUE))
#   var1 var2 var3 Sum
#1    4    5   NA   9
#2    2   NA    3   5
#3    1    2    4   7
#4   NA    3    5   8
#5    3   NA    2   5
#6    1    1    5   7
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e6 *3, replace=TRUE),
                dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:3)), ncol=3))
system.time({
df1 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(c(var1, var2, var3), na.rm = TRUE))
})
# user  system elapsed 
#  21.50    0.03   21.66 

system.time({
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    gather(var, varNum, var1:var3) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>%
    mutate(sum = sum(varNum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    spread(var, varNum)})
 # user  system elapsed 
 #  5.96    0.39    6.37 


system.time({
replace(df1, is.na(df1), 0) %>% mutate(sum = var1 + var2 + var3)
})

# user  system elapsed 
#   0.17    0.01    0.19 

system.time({
df1 %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)), var1:var3) %>% 
     mutate(Sum = Reduce(`+`, .))      
})
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.10    0.02    0.11 

system.time({
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Sum = rowSums(.[names(.)[1:3]], na.rm = TRUE))
   })
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.04    0.00    0.03
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. 
It seems from your answer that rowSums is the best and fastest way to do it. However, as I mentioned in the question the data.frame has 100 variables not only 3 variables and these 3 variables (var1 to var3) have different names and the are far away from each other like (column 3, 7 and 76). Is there anyway to have the variable name instead of 1:3 in rowSums?

Comment: @aelwan If you know the positions of those variables, you can use the `names(df)[c(3, 7, 76)]` or you can use the actual column names i.e. `rowSums(.[c("somename", "another", "var5")]`

Answer (score 10):

`rowwise()` is my go-to function. It's like `group_by()` but it treats each row as an individual group.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(c(var1, var2, var3), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. rowwise is great but it takes long time to get the result especially I have 1.3 million rows.

Answer (score 2):

Where *better* = `tidyr`:

```
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    gather(var, varNum, var1:var3) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>%
    mutate(sum = sum(varNum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    spread(var, varNum)
```

In case your dataset is poised to grow...