# Filling missing string values in dataframe R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, aggregate

I'm having trouble with something that must be quite easy in R; I want to fill the missing values in a column (of a data.frame) with the corresponding values. So like this:

```
V1    V2  
cat   tree            
cat   NA    
NA    tree  
dog   house      
NA    house    
dog   NA   
horse NA  
NA    car  
horse car
```

So the corresponding string of cat is tree, so "tree" must be filled in when there is a NA in the "cat group". "house" must be filled in when there is a NA in the "dog group" (so I must choose to take the first word of the list at 1 and 2 as the "leading" word to fill in at every number - EDIT --> it is better when the first is not leading in case of a NA is first).

There are a lot of NA's in `V1`, and a few in `V2`, and I want to fill only the NA's of `V2`.

In SPSS its done with the aggregate function, but I dont think the aggregate function in R is comparable in this case, or is it? Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: is there always exactly one distinct non-NA value in the second column for each unique value in the first column?

Comment: Yes, so in this example, "tree" always corresponds with 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace NA values with zeros in an R dataframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe)

Comment: Try this: `mydata$V3 <- ave(mydata$V2, mydata$V1, FUN = function(x) na.omit(x)[1])`

Comment: @SingleEntity, that link is not a duplicate since in this post they want different replacements per group

Comment: @Docendo discimus, this works! Thank you very much!!

Comment: This is quite a substantial edit to your initial data set invalidating most of the answers :-(.

Comment: What about the first row with `V1`== "horse" should `V2` be filled in by "car" or should it stay NA?

Comment: @ Uwe Block - Yeah, I also realise that now I've tried your code, sorry. Thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: @UweBlock - Yes, all the NA's of V2 should be filled (except when there are only NA's on both V1 and V2)

Answer (score 4):

The OP has requested that the missing values need to be filled in *by group*. So, the `zoo::na.locf()` approach might fail here.

There is a method called *update join* which can be used to fill in the missing values per group:

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.10.4 used
setDT(DT)
DT[DT[!is.na(V1)][order(V2), .(fillin = first(V2)), by = V1], on = "V1", V2 := fillin][]
#    V1    V2
# 1:  1  tree
# 2:  1  tree
# 3:  1  tree
# 4:  2 house
# 5:  2 house
# 6:  2 house
# 7:  3  lawn
# 8:  3  lawn
# 9:  4    NA
#10:  4    NA
#11: NA    NA
#12: NA  tree
```

Note that the input data have been supplemented to cover some corner cases.

#### Explanation

The approach consists of two steps. First, the values to be filled in by group are determined followed by the *update join* which modifies `DT` *in place*.

```
fill_by_group <- DT[!is.na(V1)][order(V2), .(fillin = first(V2)), by = V1]
fill_by_group
#   V1 fillin
#1:  2  house
#2:  3   lawn
#3:  1   tree
#4:  4     NA

DT[fill_by_group, on = "V1", V2 := fillin][]
```

`order(V2)` ensures that any `NA` values are sorted last, so that `first(V2)` picks the correct value to fill in.

The *update join* approach has been benchmarked as the fastest method [in another case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531059/3817004).

#### Variant using `na.omit()`

*docendo discimus* has suggested in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521174/filling-missing-string-values-in-dataframe-r/43535401?noredirect=1#comment74099793_43521174) to use `na.omit()`. This can be utilized for the *update join* as well replacing `order()`/`first()`:

```
DT[DT[!is.na(V1), .(fillin = na.omit(V2)), by = V1], on = "V1", V2 := fillin][]
```

Note that `na.omit(V2)` works as well as `na.omit(V2)[1]` or `first(na.omit(V2))`, here.

#### Data

**Edit**: The OP has changed his originally posted data set substantially. As a quick fix, I've updated the sample data below to include cases where `V1` is `NA`.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"1 tree
1 NA
1 tree
2 house
2 house
2 NA
3 NA
3 lawn
4 NA
4 NA
NA NA
NA tree")
```

Note that the data given by the OP have been supplemented to cover three additional cases:

- The first `V2` value in each group is `NA`.
- *All* `V2` values in a group are `NA`.
- `V1` is `NA.

Comment: Is `order` necessary? Is it to ensure that NA go to the bottom for the fillin to work?

Comment: @Sotos Yes, `order` is necessary if `first` is used. I have added a variant using `na.omit`.

Comment: ahh ok. So you are basically grabbing `v2[1]` so `order` makes sure it is not an NA. So `fillin` doesn't work the same as `na.locf` or `tidyr::fill`?

Comment: @Sotos The OP has requested to fill in missing values _by group_ (with the implied assumption that each group conists only of one distinct value or NA)

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't fully work (maybe I am doing it wrong?). This code treats NA's as 1 group, so every NA is filled with "tree" for example... the extra code with na.omit(V2)) also doesn't work (error: "Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join etc etc). The answer of  docendo discimus works perfect: mydata$V3 <- ave(mydata$V2, mydata$V1, FUN = function(x) na.omit(x)[1])

Comment: @W.Mooi  That's strange. Potentials problems or ideas how to track down the issue:  Do the data supplied in my answer work for you? Which version of `data.table` do you have installed? What does  `str()` return for your data?

Comment: @ Uwe Block - yes, the data of your example works. I installed version 1.10.4 of data.table. The v1 and v2 in my data are both characters, so maybe that is the cause of the problem? I also only want to fill the NA's in v2 - in this code, it also fills the non-NA v2 cells when the v1 cell is also NA. So maybe my example was not really helpful; I'm gonna edit my OP

Comment: @W.Mooi If there are NAs in V1 that might change the game.

Comment: @W.Mooi I've quickly update my answer to cover cases where `V1` is `NA`. The solution should work also with your new data set.

Comment: @Uwe, why not just use `df[!is.na(V1), V2 := first(na.omit(V2)), by = V1]` instead of a join?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `dplyr` and try:

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(V2 = unique(V2[!is.na(V2)]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below:

```
mydata<-read.table(text="1 tree
1 NA
1 tree
2 house
2 house
2 NA")

mydata[is.na(mydata$V2),]$V2<-mydata[which(is.na(mydata$V2))-1,]$V2
```

Comment: This approach works only for the given data set. It fails when the data include groups which start with `NA`.

Comment: without a loop, this also fails for data with consecutive more than one `NA` within a group