# Matching two dataframes and pulling in a maximum value

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, max

I have two tables:

df_workingFile

```
      group   v   
1      a    110 
2      a    90 
3      b    57 
4      b    53
```

df_groupIDs

```
  group   
1      a 
2      b
```

I want to pull in the maximum value from df_workingFile for a group label into df_groupIDs

df_groupIDs

```
  groups   max
1      a   110
2      b    57
```

I have code that does this, but it's really slow with large datasets.

```
data.frame(df_groupIDs, maxValue = 
   sapply(df_groupIDs$group, function(newCol) 
   max(subset(df_workingFile, newCol == df_workingFile$group)$v)))
```

Any suggestions on how to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 4):

With data.table, this is an "update join":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_groupIDs)
setDT(df_workingFile)

df_groupIDs[ , mx := df_workingFile[.(.SD$group), on=.(group), max(v), by=.EACHI]$V1 ]

#    group  mx
# 1:     a 110
# 2:     b  57
```

The `.SD$group` part is not idiomatic. It should just be `.SD`, but there's an [open bug preventing that](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926).

---

*How it works*

The syntax for a join is `x[i, on=]`, where `i` is used to look up rows in `x` according to the rules in `on=`. The syntax for an update is `x[, var := expr]`. Here, these are combined like `x[, var := x2[.SD, on=]]`, where `.SD` refers to the subset of data from `x`. We can equivalently write the `expr` as

```
df_workingFile[df_groupIDs, on=.(group), max(v), by=.EACHI]$V1
```

See the documentation in `?data.table` regarding what `by=.EACHI` is doing. `V1` is just the default name given to computed results (in this case, `max(v)`).

---

*Performance*

> I have code that does this, but it's really slow with large datasets.

This approach should be fairly efficient since (i) it assigns to the existing `df_groupIDs` table instead of creating a new one; (ii) it only computes the max on the groups that appear in `df_groupIDs` (instead of all that appear in `df_workingFile`); and (iii) the grouped maximum is optimized (see `?GForce`).

For an example comparing timings (of update join vs dplyr, match, etc), see [merge data.frames based on year and fill in missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521708/merge-data-frames-based-on-year-and-fill-in-missing-values/43531059#43531059) .

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the maximum for each ID first in `df_workingFile`. After that, conduct a `left_join`.

```
library(dplyr)

df_max <- df_workingFile %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(max = max(v))

df_final <- df_groupIDs %>% left_join(df_max, by = "group")
```

Here is the base R approach.

```
df_max <- aggregate(v ~ group, data = df_workingFile, FUN = max)

df_final <- merge(df_groupIDs, df_max, by = "group", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: I guess they want the new col assigned to existing table df_groupIDs, like `df_groupIDs$col <- ...` in base r.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think `df_max` is ready to do a merge with `df_groupIDs`. I will update my answer to include that part @Frank.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that uses `tapply` to calculate the maximum values and then adds them to the second data.frame with `transform`, using `match` to find the proper indices.

```
# calculate maximum values
vals <- with(df_workingFile, tapply(v, group, max))
# add new variable
transform(df_groupIDs, max=vals[match(group, names(vals))])
  group max
a     a 110
b     b  57
```

To add the variable, a more standard notation would be

```
df_groupIDs$max <- vals[match(df_groupIDs$group, names(vals))]
```