# Conditionally remove of rows in dataframe which includes NA

Tags: r, select, na

My example df:

```
  a1 a2 a3 a4
1  1  1  4  6
2  1  2  3  2
3  2 NA  5 NA
4  2  5  6  3
5  3  1  1  2
6  3  3  2  6
```

"If `a4 == 6` then delete this row."
So, I would like to delete (only!) row 1 and 6 in this example.

I know this works:

```
df_1 <- df[-c(1, 6), ]
```

But I'm looking for a more general solution.

I tried the most obvious way:

```
attach(df)
df_1 <- df[ which(a4 != 6),]
detach(df)
```

However, this deletes all `NA` as well and I would like to keep them.

```
  a1 a2 a3 a4
2  1  2  3  2
4  2  5  6  3
5  3  1  1  2
```

Then I tried:

```
df_1 <-df[!(df$a4 == 6),]
```

but then row 3 dances limbo and the whole row gets `NA`

```
   a1 a2 a3 a4
2   1  2  3  2
NA NA NA NA NA
4   2  5  6  3
5   3  1  1  2
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace NA values with zeros in an R dataframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe)

Comment: @agerom the link is not a dupe, OP is not trying to replace NAs by anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%in%` instead of `==` to properly handle `NA`s:

```
df[!(df$a4 %in% 6),]
#  a1 a2 a3 a4
#2  1  2  3  2
#3  2 NA  5 NA
#4  2  5  6  3
#5  3  1  1  2
```

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't know something like "%in%" exists. TIL :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use a logical index with `is.na` to remove

```
df[!(df$a4 == 6 & !is.na(df$a4)),]
```

as it will return the whole dataset when the element is not present

Or it can be written (as @thelatemail commented)

```
df[df$a4!=6 | (is.na(df$a4)),]
```

Comment: Why the double `!`? `df[df$a4!=6 | is.na(df$a4),]`