# Replace NA with a Default value

Tags: r, na

One of my variable is about the type of Garbage Disposal.Heres what the summary of the field in R.

```
  summary(train$GarageType)

 2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    NA's 
      6     870      19      88       9     387      81
```

Now, I know that where ever NA is, there is No Garbage Disposal in place. Hence I need to put a value like 'null' of ''  .

How to give train$GarageType <- 'null' when train$garbage = NA >

```
Expected OutPut will be like
      summary(train$GarageType)

     2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    NULL
          6     870      19      88       9     387      81
```

Such that Null is a valid kind.

Closest solution I got is

```
> x<-train
> x$GarageType <- factor(ifelse( is.na(x$GarageType), "NULL", x$GarageType))
> summary(x$GarageType)
   1    2    3    4    5    6 **NULL** 
   6  870   19   88    9  387   81 
> summary(train$GarageType)
 2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    **NA's** 
      6     870      19      88       9     387      81
```

Now, I could rename NA with NULL but others like 2Types , Attchd etc  became 1,2 etc.

Comment: See [section 2.7 of CRAN's "An Introduction to R"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors).

Comment: Can you add some exampe code with `dput(head(train$GarageType))` and then tell us what you are hoping to see as a result? If you are trying to replace NA values than that is already answered here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe - but substitute "null" or "" for 0.

Comment: If you replace NA values with "NULL" in a numeric variable, then it will become a character variable. Make sure this won't affect your analysis.

Comment: Expected needs identify NULL or Empty as a TYPE of Garage

   Expected OutPut will be like
      ` summary(train$GarageType)`
    
        ` 2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    NULL/Empty
              6     870      19      88       9     387      81`

Comment: `NA` is the best value to use there.  `NULL` is not allowed in data frames, and using a character `"null"` would coerce columns to undesirable types.

Comment: Either NULL or Empty or NILL or XYZ  ,  I want to give a default value substituting all NA for a particular column. I am not particular about NULL alone, some string which I would like to substitute for Null

Comment: @JensLeerssen , That Solution does not work in this case.
The difference is 'GarbageType' is the only colunm that I want to change. And its not numeric value either.
I got the result <br/>
 summary(x$GarageType) <br/>
   1    2    3    4    5    6 NILL <br/>
   6  870   19   88    9  387   81 <br/>
What I need is <br/>
 2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    NILL <br/>
      6      870      19           88         9           387          81  <br/>

As I give Summary, I need NA to be replaced by Null or Nill or some custome value.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you need to use ifelse( ). There are two ways of doing this.

```
#Creating a simple reproducible example:
x <- dplyr::tibble(GarageType = c(1:20, rep(NA,20))

#Changing the column directly

x$GarageType <- ifelse(is.na(x$GarageType)==TRUE, "NULL", x$GarageType)

#Creating a new dataframe with a column (needs tidyverse)

x <- x %>% mutate(GarageType = ifelse(is.na(GarageType) == TRUE, "NULL", GarageType))
```

Comment: Didnt work,
 `summary(x$GarageType)
 2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    NA's 
      6     870      19      88       9     387      81 `
...   After..... `summary(x$GarageType)
   Length     Class      Mode 
     1460 character character`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace NA of only 1 variable then we can add one new column in the data frame, apply function on that and replace old column/variable

> df$newcol <- NA

Then use the for loop and if else condition

> 

```
for(i in 1 to nrow(df)){
    If(is.na(df[i,oldcol])){ 
    Df[i,newcol]<-"null" 
    }else{ 
    Df[i,newcol]<- df[i,oldcol] 
    } 
    Next
}
```

Then assign this new var values to old var

> Df$oldcol <- df$newcol

Answer (score 0):

I found same question and answer at,
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/41522/salb

I tried and I got the expected results.

```
> df <- train 
> levels <- levels(df$GarageType)
> summary(levels)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        6 character character 
> levels
[1] "2Types"  "Attchd"  "Basment" "BuiltIn" "CarPort" "Detchd" 
> levels[length(levels) + 1] <- "None"
> df$GarageType <- factor(df$GarageType, levels = levels)
> summary(df$GarageType)
 2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    None    NA's 
      6     870      19      88       9     387       0      81 
> df$GarageType[is.na(df$GarageType)] <- "None"
**> summary(df$GarageType)
 2Types  Attchd Basment BuiltIn CarPort  Detchd    None 
      6     870      19      88       9     387      81**
```