# How to remove a character in the dataframe using the stringi package?

Tags: r, dataframe, stringi

I currently have a dataframe of stock KPIs and I would like to remove the "$" character from the data. However, I can only use one line of code in addition to the mandatory usage of the **stringi** package. Looking at the documentation, the "**stri_replace_all_fixed**" was the function that stood out to me, but upon running that function, my data frame lost its formatting. I tried combining both the **lapply** and the **stri_replace_all_fixed** functions to no avail. Pointers on how to address this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post an example dataset using `dput(head(yourdataframe))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `library(stringi)`

```
yourdataframe[] <- lapply(yourdataframe, stri_replace_all_regex,"\\$", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Dummy data
dta <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 10)) %>%
    mutate(value = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE) %>% paste("$"))

# scrub a dub (using dplyr)
dta %>% mutate_all(funs(stri_replace_all_fixed(., "$", "")))
```

and it is one of the faster approaches, too: [replacement drag races](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585689/5088194)

Answer (score 0):

An update (as November 2022) on @leerssej ansewer as `funs()` was deprecated:

```
# Dummy data
dta <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 10)) %>%
    mutate(value = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE) %>% paste("$"))

# scrub a dub (using dplyr)
dta %>% mutate_all(~stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(., "$", ""))
```