# Microbenchmarking modify in place data.table functions in R

Tags: r, data.table, microbenchmark

I am trying to compare different value replacement function speeds, but I am having a difficult time setting them onto a level playing field when I include `data.table`s `set()` and `:=` functions.

I had set up my microbenchmark to have each function modify the dataframe locally so that I wouldn''t need to recreate a fresh dataframe each time. Like so:

```
# create replicable dataframe filled with 20% NAs and numeric values
set.seed(42)
Book1 <- 
    as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, runif(2, min = 1, max = 4)),   
                         3e6*10, replace=TRUE),  
                  dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:3)), ncol=3))
```

Which looks like:

> ```
> > str(Book1)
> 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  3 variables:
> $ var1: num  NA 3.81 3.74 3.74 3.81 ...
> $ var2: num  3.74 3.81 NA NA 3.81 ...
> $ var3: num  NA 3.74 3.81 3.74 NA ...
> ```

Then when I wrap the timings in `local()` or another function I can spare rebuilding the raw dataframe anew for each function for each trial that works diligently at replacing the `NA`s with `0`s.

*for example:*

```
# Base R functions (from alexis_laz)
baseR.for.loop = function(x) { 
    for(j in 1:ncol(x))
        x[[j]][is.na(x[[j]])] = 0
}
```

> ```
> > system.time({local(baseR_for(Book1))})
> user  system elapsed 
> 0.28    0.14    0.42
> ```

and the dataframe is left unchanged.

> ```
> > str(Book1)
> 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  3 variables:
> $ var1: num  NA 3.81 3.74 3.74 3.81 ...
> $ var2: num  3.74 3.81 NA NA 3.81 ...
> $ var3: num  NA 3.74 3.81 3.74 NA ...
> ```

Now when I run modify in place `data.table` functions to do the same, the original dataframe is getting modified even though I am wrapping the action in both a `local()` *and* a `function()`.

```
library(data.table)
DT.set.nms = function(DT) {
    for (j in names(DT))
        set(DT,which(is.na(DT[[j]])),j,0)
}
```

> ```
> > system.time({local(DT.set.nms(Book1))})
> user  system elapsed 
> 0.14    0.00    0.14 
> > str(Book1)
> 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  3 variables:
> $ var1: num  0 3.81 3.74 3.74 3.81 ...
> $ var2: num  3.74 3.81 0 0 3.81 ...
> $ var3: num  0 3.74 3.81 3.74 0 ...
> ```

With some more study I discovered that the odd behavior was being caused by `data.table`s over allocation of memory and modify in place capabilities. While these are in fact amazingly powerful, particularly as I had not thought this was possible in R, they are not very helpful for my current microbenchmarking approach.)

So my initial question is:

#### How can I run a suite of functions side by side in `microbenchmark` and get the functions to all operate on a level playing field?

This is how I had been doing these NA replacement analyses (and how I have seen microbenchmarks typically performed).

```
library(microbenchmark)
perf_results <- microbenchmark(
    baseR_for        = local(baseR.for.loop(Book1)),
    baseR.replace    = local(replace(Book1, is.na(Book1), 0)),
    baseR.sbst.rssgn = local(Book1[is.na(Book1)] <- 0),
    times = 5L
)
```

> ```
> > print(perf_results)
> Unit: milliseconds
> expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
> baseR_for  423.1889  464.4622  569.9093  636.3708  648.8386  676.6857     5
> baseR.replace 1113.9829 1204.0874 1215.1211 1212.5199 1214.8138 1330.2012     5
> baseR.sbst.rssgn 1156.9010 1161.4675 1262.6653 1218.1743 1360.4346 1416.3490     5
> ```
>
> and the dataframe is left untouched.
>
> ```
> > str(Book1)
> 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  3 variables:
> $ var1: num  NA 3.81 3.74 3.74 3.81 ...
> $ var2: num  3.74 3.81 NA NA 3.81 ...
> $ var3: num  NA 3.74 3.81 3.74 NA ...
> ```

If I add the datatable functions to the analyses, they 'destroy' the original dataframe after the first time that it was passed into the DT functions. So to deal with this I was considering including an action to copy the original dataset each time, so each of the functions act only on the copy. Additionally, I was thinking that I would have to wrap every approach in its own custom function to keep being a custom function from becoming a confounding variable. This thus looks like:

```
baseR.sbst.rssgn <- function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x }
baseR.replace <- function(x) { replace(x, is.na(x), 0)}

perf_results <- microbenchmark(
    baseR.for.loop   = baseR_for(copy(Book1)),
    baseR.replace    = baseR.replace(copy(Book1)),
    baseR.sbst.rssgn = baseR.sbst.rssgn(copy(Book1)),
    DT.set.nms       = DT.set.nms(copy(Book1)),
    times = 5L
)
```

This seems to work, *and* the dataframe is left untouched, but I am still left wondering...
***Is there a better approach to performing microbenchmarks on `data.table`s modify in place functions?***

Comment: Using `copy` is the way to do it. Fwiw, ime, if `system.time`/`times=1` is not good enough to tell you the answer, then you're not optimizing the right thing.

Comment: Context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe/41585689#41585689

Comment: @uwe - it is indeed! Not sure why all my searches didn't pull this up. It looks like `copy()` really is the best approach then, and a great idea to benchmark it separately, too. Thank you!