# Change all Factor NA's in dataset R

Tags: r, dataset, na, factors

I have a dataset that I want to use for building a Decision Tree in R studio. I have quite a few factors which are empty. I want to change all Factors that are empty in the dataset to "No Data", I have over 100 of these so I don't want to do them one by one, I'd rather be able to change all of them at once.

Example of data (Please note that these are all factors, I know that when it's put into R they are numerics but I don't know how to show factors in a replicated way as I read in the data from a csv):

```
Outcome=c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
VarA=c(1,1,NA,0,0,NA)
VarB=c(0,NA,1,1,NA,0)
VarC=c(0,NA,1,1,NA,0)
VarD=c(0,1,NA,0,0,0)
VarE=c(0,NA,1,1,NA,NA)
VarF=c(NA,NA,0,1,0,0)
VarG=c(0,NA,1,1,NA,0)
df=as.data.frame(cbind(Outcome, VarA, VarB,VarC,VarD,VarE,VarF,VarG))
```

Comment: Based on your example, variables are all numeric.  `replace(df, is.na(df), "No Data")`

Comment: Wouldn't this mess up your decision tree calculation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe

Comment: @PoGibas has a point here. You should of course only do this with factorial data and not with numeric.

Comment: @akrun  I don't know how to show an example where the data is Factors? As I read the data in through CSV

Comment: If you have factor columns, then you may need to add 'No Data' as one of the levels before changing the NA to 'No Data'

Comment: @akrun would I have to do this for each column separately or can I do it for every factor column at once?

Comment: If these are factor columns, it is better not to mix the columns, so, try `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {levels(x) <- c(levels(x), "No Data"); replace(x, is.na(x), "No Data")})`

Comment: @akrun Thanks! That's worked perfectly, if you put it as an answer I'll mark it off! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we have `factor` columns and wanted to replace one of the values with a new value, either call the `factor` again or add the new value as one of the `levels` of the factor before doing the change.  Assuming that we have to recode for variables other than the first column, loop through the columns with `lapply`, add 'No Data' as one of the `levels` and then `replace` the NA elements with "No Data", and finally assign the `list` output to the columns of interest

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
        levels(x) <- c(levels(x), "No Data")
         replace(x, is.na(x), "No Data")
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- "NoData"
```

Comment: I've tried this for the factors and none of them change