# Replace Values with NA by same position in another df

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
 Col1     Col2      Col3     Col4
    1        0         3        5 
   NA        1        NA        0
    2        3        NA        5

df2
 Col1     Col2      Col3     Col4
    7        0         5        7 
    0        8         0        0
    9        9         6        2
```

How do I replace `df2` with `NA`'s by same position of `df1`?

I want my final df3 to look like this:

```
 Col1     Col2      Col3     Col4
    7        0         5        7 
   NA        8        NA        0
    9        9        NA        2
```

Comment: `df3 <- df2; df3[is.na(df1)] <- NA`

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [*How do I replace NA values with zeros in an R dataframe?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8161836/2204410)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion base R is better equiped for that compared to the `tidyverse`:

```
df2[is.na(df1)] <- NA
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df2
>   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
> 1    7    0    5    7
> 2   NA    8   NA    0
> 3    9    9   NA    2
> ```

And if you really need `df3`:

```
df3 <- df2
df3[is.na(df1)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df3=`is.na<-`(df2,is.na(df1))
df3
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1    7    0    5    7
2   NA    8   NA    0
3    9    9   NA    2
```

or even

```
df3=replace(df2,is.na(df1),NA)
 df3
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1    7    0    5    7
2   NA    8   NA    0
3    9    9   NA    2
```

Comment: note that `replace` is nothing more than a wrapper aroud `x[condition] <- value`

Comment: @jaap with your solution, you are making a copy of the dataframe.. while this has no copy made.