# R programming - treat NA in a file as 0

Tags: r

Really simple question, to which I haven't been able to Google/find an answer.

I have a simple file - "test.txt"

```
Gender arch1
M      99
F      97
M      NA
```

I load this into a resultset using read.table - works fine.

```
attach(resultset)
```

Now, I want *_something_* that will give me

```
mean(arch1, [_SOMETHING_]) = 65.3 (and *_NOT_* 98)
```

i.e. not na.rm = T or similar. Basically, I want to treat NA as 0 - and I don't want to do something complicated like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe) with matrices and dataframes.

Just NA = 0 from the file. Surely, I can't be the first person to have wanted this? And I don't want discussions about how NA and 0 are not the same thing. I think it's perfectly valid to want to calculate an average even over missing students!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
sum(arch1, na.rm = T)/length(arch1)
```

Comment: Why "sum" - I asked for a mean? I think I'm right in saying that sum(arch1, na.rm = T) will be the equivalent of summing arch1 with NA = 0 anyway?

Comment: The `na.rm = TRUE` is so the function doesn't return NA. Dividing by the length gives the mean.

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the `NA`s with zeros before using `mean`:

```
mean(replace(arch1, is.na(arch1), 0))
# [1] 65.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

you could replace the NA by zero with `resultset$arch1[is.na(resultset$arch1)]=0` and then compute the mean of the `arch1` column

Comment: > resultset$arch1[is.na(resultset$arch1)]=0
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, arch1, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 9
>

Answer (score -1):

Below is my suggestion on how to implement the solution to which I have now given as the correct answer:

```
avg_without_NA = function(vec) 
{
  my_ans = sum(vec, na.rm = T)/length(vec)
  return(my_ans)
}
```

So, now all I have to do is make a simple function call and my code is encapsulated in! Simpler all round, and easier to read!