# How can I repeat a string of code for different variables of the same dataframe?

Tags: r, loops

Here there's an example:

```
car <- data.frame(matrix(c(2,NA,5,NA,7,6), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow = FALSE))
colnames(car) <- c("a","b")
```

How can I write this part without repeating the code?

```
car$a[is.na(car$a)] <- 0
car$b[is.na(car$b)] <- 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace NA values with zeros in an R dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe)

Comment: `car[is.na(car)] <- 0`