# Filling Null Values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to go through an entire dataframe and replace null values with zero. There are a large amount of columns so this would be cumbersome to do column by column. I was thinking of something on the lines of

```
for (Var in names(housing.test.df)) {
  for (row in housing.test.df[,Var]) {
    if(is.na(housing.test.df[row,Var]))
    {housing.test.df[row,Var] <- 0}
         }
  }
```

Where housing.test.df is the dataframe

Comment: Try : `housing.test.df[is.na(housing.test.df)] <- 0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe