# NA replacing with blanks

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

I have used the same method for replacing NA's with blanks or other characters but for some reason this one is not working. I want to replace the NA's on my dataframe to blanks (columns year and Annual). What am I doing wrong?

```
shad.92 <- structure(list(year = c(1992, NA, NA, NA, NA), type = c("all age abundance index", 
"adjusted number of fish older than age 0 measured", "adjusted total number of fish measured", 
"percent YOY", "YOY abundance index"), September = c(755, 0, 
565, 100, 755), October = c(530, 0, 434, 100, 530), November = c(463, 
0, 338, 100, 463), December = c(266, 1, 136, 99.3, 264), Annual = c(2014, 
NA, NA, NA, 2012)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried this with no luck:

```
shad.92 <- shad.92[is.na(shad.92)] <- ""
```

I then tried one column at the time starting with year:

```
shad.92$year <- as.character(shad.92$year)
    shad.92$year[is.na(shad.92$year)] <- " "
    shad.92
```

But I get quotation marks instead of blanks ("")

[image]

Comment: Some of the columns are numeric and by doing the replacement to `' '`, it converts to character

Comment: The quotation marks are so you can see that you've put a space there, which doesn't seem like what you actually want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace NA values with zeros in an R dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe)

Comment: @camille not exactly the same, similar yes, same no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `""` in a `tibble` it displays the elements of that column with the quotation marks. However `""` is a blank. When you use base R's `data.frame` the quotations are not printed. Try the below after you run your code.

```
as.data.frame(shad.92)
```

But if you want to print this as a `kable`, the `kable` should not print the `""` itself (at least not to the terminal; I didn't try printing to HTML).

```
library(knitr)
kable(shad.92)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mutate_at` with `replace_na`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
shad.92 %>% 
       mutate_at(vars(year, Annual), replace_na, '')
# A tibble: 5 x 7
#  year   type                                              September October November December Annual
#  <chr>  <chr>                                                 <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> 
#1 "1992" all age abundance index                                 755     530      463    266   "2014"
#2 ""     adjusted number of fish older than age 0 measured         0       0        0      1   ""    
#3 ""     adjusted total number of fish measured                  565     434      338    136   ""    
#4 ""     percent YOY                                             100     100      100     99.3 ""    
#5 ""     YOY abundance index                                     755     530      463    264   "2012"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun but I am still get the " " instead of blanks.

Comment: `""` is blank. What are you expecting?

Comment: @Salvador Not able to reproduce what you mentioned.  If you need to change the format of print, use `%>% as.data.frame` at the end

Comment: I think the confusion is that print displays `""` in `data.frame` as blank and `tibble` displays `""` as `""`. Actually `data.frame` does't show quotation marks in strings

Comment: Mosquite, I don't want quotation marks, I just want a blank field. I am printing a kable and I don't want quotation marks showing.

Comment: Does it show the quotation marks when you print as a `kable`?

Comment: Both of you are correct. My dataset is a tibble and needed to convert to data.frame. What a great lesson. Is there a way to give credit to both?

Answer (score 3):

*A `base` solution using `replace`:*

```r
as.data.frame(replace(shad.92, is.na(shad.92), ""))

#>   year                                              type September October
#> 1 1992                           all age abundance index       755     530
#> 2      adjusted number of fish older than age 0 measured         0       0
#> 3                 adjusted total number of fish measured       565     434
#> 4                                            percent YOY       100     100
#> 5                                    YOY abundance index       755     530
#>   November December Annual
#> 1      463      266   2014
#> 2        0        1       
#> 3      338      136       
#> 4      100     99.3       
#> 5      463      264   2012
```