# Find gender based on a specific dataframe

Tags: r

Having a dataframe with have the gender of specific names

```
dfgender <- data.frame(name = c("Helen","Erik"), gender = c("F","M"))
```

How is it possible to use the previous data frame in order to check the names of another column of a dataframe and insert "Neutral" if the name is not in the list of gender dataframe:
Example of the dataframe with the names:

```
dfnames <- data.frame(names = c("Helen", "Von", "Erik", "Brook"))
```

Example of expected output

```
dfnames <- data.frame(name = c("Helen", "Von", "Erik", "Brook"), gender = c("F", "Neutral", "M", "Neutral"))
```

Comment: Since you have a lookup table already, you can do a left-join and then fill in `NA` values. A couple dozen options for doing that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8161836/5325862)

Answer (score 3):

`left_join` + `replace_na` should do:

```
dfnames %>% left_join(dfgender, by=c('names' = 'name')) %>% 
  mutate(gender = gender %>% as.character %>% replace_na('Neutral'))

# names  gender
# 1 Helen       F
# 2   Von Neutral
# 3  Erik       M
# 4 Brook Neutral
```

Answer (score 1):

The (experimental) `rows_update` could be an intuitive compliment to @Juan C's answer:

```r
library(dplyr)

dfnames |>
  mutate(gender = "Neutral") |>
  rows_update(rename(dfgender, names = name), "names")
```

Output:

```r
  names  gender
1 Helen       F
2   Von Neutral
3  Erik       M
4 Brook Neutral
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution similar to Juan C's but with, I think, a simpler replacement of NAs:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfgender <- data.frame(name = c("Helen","Erik"), gender = c("F","M"))
dfnames <- data.frame(names = c("Helen", "Von", "Erik", "Brook"))

dfnames %>%
  left_join(dfgender, by = c("names" = "name")) %>%
  replace_na(list(gender = "Neutral"))
#   names  gender
# 1 Helen       F
# 2   Von Neutral
# 3  Erik       M
# 4 Brook Neutral
```

And here's another solution with no `tidyr` dependency:

```r
library(dplyr)

dfgender <- data.frame(name = c("Helen","Erik"), gender = c("F","M"))
dfnames <- data.frame(names = c("Helen", "Von", "Erik", "Brook"))

dfnames %>%
  left_join(dfgender, by = c("names" = "name")) %>%
  mutate(gender = coalesce(gender, "Neutral"))
#   names  gender
# 1 Helen       F
# 2   Von Neutral
# 3  Erik       M
# 4 Brook Neutral
```