# Using vector for recoding variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, vector, recode

In a recent project, I have quite a big data frame.
And I'd like to reprogram certain variables using a vector that I defined earlier.

I know there are many other ways to recode the data, but I was wondering if I could use the vector because it seems like an elegant solution.

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1,2,2,1),
  B = c(1,1,1,2),
  C = c(2,2,1,2)
)


vector <- c(
  "A",
  "B"
)
```

Consider this example. Here I have created a vector, which consists of 2 Names in the Data set.
Can I now use this vector to reprogram the data frame?
E.g. I'd like to change all '1' to a '0' in the columns 'A' and 'B'.

I tried this:

```
df[df[,vector]==1] <- 0
```

Yet this code only works, when i define the Vector like this:

```
vector <- c(
  "A",
  "B",
  "C"
)
```

Therefore, when it includes all the variables in the data frame.

If I use the same code, but the vector does only include 'A' and 'B', i get the following error:

> ```
> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df[, vector] == 2, value = 1) : 
>   unsupported matrix index in replacement
> ```

Do you have an Idea on how this might work?

Kind regards

Comment: `df[, vector] <- replace(df[, vector], df[, vector] == 1, 0)`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Do you think it is also possible to use a vector to change the class of those columns? like so: ```ds[,varnames]<- as.numeric(ds[,varnames])``` That didn't work for me though...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: ```ds[,varnames] <- sapply(ds[,varnames],as.numeric)```

Comment: Have a look at [Replace all NA with FALSE in selected columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7279089/10488504)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mutate(across())` from `dplyr`.

```
mutate(df,across(all_of(vector),\(v) replace(v,v==1,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A *base* way could be to subset `df` with `vector` and then subset this where `df[vector]==1`.

```
df[,vector][df[,vector]==1] <- 0
#df[vector][df[vector]==1] <- 0 #Alternative

df
#  A B C
#1 0 0 2
#2 2 0 2
#3 2 0 1
#4 0 2 2
```

Another way could be to use a for loop.

```
for(i in vector) df[[i]][df[[i]]==1] <- 0
#for(i in vector) df[,i][df[,i]==1] <- 0 #Variant
```

---

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(check=FALSE,
langtang = local({df <- dplyr::mutate(df,dplyr::across(all_of(vector),\(v) replace(v,v==1,0)))}),
"Maël" = local({df[, vector] <- replace(df[, vector], df[, vector] == 1, 0)}),
GKi = local({df[,vector][df[,vector]==1] <- 0}),
GKi2 = local(for(i in vector) df[,i][df[,i]==1] <- 0),
GKi3 = local(for(i in vector) df[[i]][df[[i]]==1] <- 0)
)
#  expression      min median itr/s…¹ mem_al…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>   <dbl> <bch:by>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 langtang     2.66ms    3ms    299.   7.89KB    8.37   143     4   478ms <NULL>
#2 Maël       219.56µs  241µs   4017.     280B   12.3   1955     6   487ms <NULL>
#3 GKi        222.48µs  243µs   4013.     280B   12.3   1951     6   486ms <NULL>
#4 GKi2       106.96µs  116µs   8452.     280B   12.3   4119     6   487ms <NULL>
#5 GKi3        60.75µs   65µs  15217.     280B   14.4   7398     7   486ms <NULL>
```

The `for` loop is about 3 times faster than the other *base* variants and about 50 times faster than the *dplyr* variant. All *base* variants use less memory compared to the *dplyr* variant.