# What is the best way to turn variables with either an answer or NA into dummy variables?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have example data as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(Q1_A = c("This is a reason", NA, "This is a reason", NA),
                 Q1_B = c("This is another reason", "This is another reason", NA, NA))
```

Each answer had multiple answer possibilities. As a result, they had to be split out.`NA`s are therefore also not real `NA`s

I would like to run a regression in the form:

```
lm( y ~ Q1_A + Q1_B + ... + )
```

Which then shows as the output:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Q1_A         Q1_B
   34.66099     -0.02058     -1.58728
```

I guess this means I need to turn all the NA values to base levels.

What is the best way to turn these variables into dummies?

Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(Q1_A = c("This is a reason", "Baselevel", "This is a reason", "Baselevel"),
                 Q1_B = c("This is another reason", "This is another reason", "Baselevel", "Baselevel"))
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing both long and wide formats. I would create an ID for each question and list all corresponding answers under the same ID, e.g., with a new row for each answer.

Comment: @Julian I have added some more information.

Comment: @dufei Could you elaborate a bit, or provide some link? What would be the benefit of your suggestion?

Comment: Try: `df[is.na(df)] <- "Baselevel"`. See also [How do I replace NA values with zeros in an R dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8161836/10488504) or [Replace all NA with FALSE in selected columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7279089/10488504).

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr::replace_na`:

```
df |> mutate(across(starts_with("Q"), ~relevel(as.factor(tidyr::replace_na(., "Baselevel")),  ref = "Baselevel")))
```

For `Q1_A` you get

```
[1] This is a reason Baselevel        This is a reason Baselevel       
Levels: Baselevel This is a reason
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to additionally set the "Baselevel" as the baselevel for the factors?

Comment: I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

When working with data like this we usually transform the reason columns into `0` and `1` dummies, while the column name indicates the reason. When the reasons are rather long we use a lookup data.frame to look the column names up when needed.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Q1_A:Q1_B),
                   ~ ifelse(!is.na(.x), 1, 0))
            )

#>   Q1_A Q1_B
#> 1    1    1
#> 2    0    1
#> 3    1    0
#> 4    0    0

# create lookup df and use when necessary
lookup_df <- df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ na.omit(unique(.x)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything())

lookup_df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   name  value                 
#>   <chr> <chr>                 
#> 1 Q1_A  This is a reason      
#> 2 Q1_B  This is another reason
```

Data from OP

```r
df <- data.frame(Q1_A = c("This is a reason", NA, "This is a reason", NA),
                 Q1_B = c("This is another reason", "This is another reason", NA, NA))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>