# Warning message: In `...` : invalid factor level, NA generated

Tags: r, warnings, r-faq

I don't understand why I got this warning message.

```
> fixed <- data.frame("Type" = character(3), "Amount" = numeric(3))
> fixed[1, ] <- c("lunch", 100)
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "lunch") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> fixed
  Type Amount
1 <NA>    100
2           0
3           0
```

Answer (score 223, accepted):

The warning message is because your "Type" variable was made a factor and "lunch" was not a defined level. Use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` flag when making your data frame to force "Type" to be a character.

```
> fixed <- data.frame("Type" = character(3), "Amount" = numeric(3))
> str(fixed)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Type  : Factor w/ 1 level "": NA 1 1
 $ Amount: chr  "100" "0" "0"
> 
> fixed <- data.frame("Type" = character(3), "Amount" = numeric(3),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> fixed[1, ] <- c("lunch", 100)
> str(fixed)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Type  : chr  "lunch" "" ""
 $ Amount: chr  "100" "0" "0"
```

Comment: @David Why does R convert it into Factor?

Comment: Because that is the default setting in the `data.frame()` function (and it is default because that is the what most users want the vast majority of the time).

Answer (score 49):

If you are reading directly from CSV file then do like this.

```
myDataFrame <- read.csv("path/to/file.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: stringAsFactors is throwing an error: unused argument (stringAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: `stringsAsFactors` - `strings` needs to be plural (@Coliban)

Answer (score 28):

Here is a **flexible approach**, it can be used in all cases, in particular:

1. to **affect only one column**, or
2. the `dataframe` has been obtained from applying previous operations (e.g. **not immediately opening a file**, or creating a new data frame).

---

First, *un-factorize* a string using the `as.character` function, and, then, *re-factorize* with the `as.factor` (or simply `factor`) function:

```r
fixed <- data.frame("Type" = character(3), "Amount" = numeric(3))

# Un-factorize (as.numeric can be use for numeric values)
#              (as.vector  can be use for objects - not tested)
fixed$Type <- as.character(fixed$Type)
fixed[1, ] <- c("lunch", 100)

# Re-factorize with the as.factor function or simple factor(fixed$Type)
fixed$Type <- as.factor(fixed$Type)
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to fix this is to add a new factor to your column.  Use the levels function to determine how many factors you have and then add a new factor.

```
    > levels(data$Fireplace.Qu)
    [1] "Ex" "Fa" "Gd" "Po" "TA"
    > levels(data$Fireplace.Qu) = c("Ex", "Fa", "Gd", "Po", "TA", "None")
    [1] "Ex"   "Fa"   "Gd"   "Po"   " TA"  "None"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar issue which data retrieved from .xlsx file. Unfortunately, I could not find the proper answer here. I handled it on my own  with dplyr as below which might help others:

```
#install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)
extracted_df <- read.xlsx("test.xlsx", sheetName='Sheet1', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Replace all NAs in a data frame with "G" character
extracted_df[is.na(extracted_df)] <- "G"
```

However, I could not handle it with the [`readxl` package](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/) which does not have similar parameter to the `stringsAsFactors`. For the reason, I have moved to the `xlsx` package.