# Warning message when using If(...) function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, warnings, conditional-statements

I'm having some problems with if function in R.

First I tried this:

```
test<-matrix(10,3,3)
if(test[2,2]==10) {test[2,2]<-5}
```

Ok, it's doing what I want. So, I will try this:

```
if(Hylo.Measures[i,3]=="CLc0006x") {Hylo.Measures[i,3]<-"CLc0005x"}
```

Ops! I got the following message:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "CLc0005x") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I couldn't figure out what is going on here!

What obvious step am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid factor level, NA generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/invalid-factor-level-na-generated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That third column is a factor variable; you might want to check your code to make sure that is what you actually want. Anyway, you can add the level manually if you're sure it's what you want to do. Here's an example of adding a level on `iris`

```
R>iris$Species[5] <- "hahah"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 5, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

R>levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "hahah")
R>iris$Species[5] <- "hahah"
R>iris[5,]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
5            5         3.6          1.4         0.2   hahah
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that the character values in your real `data.frame` are being stored as factors, meaning that the elements of `Hylo.Measures[ ,3]` (at least) are limited to a discrete set of levels. `"CLc0005x` is not present in any of your rows, and therefore is not a valid level for that column.

Try executing `str(Hylo.Measures)`, and you will see what I mean.

The easiest way to address this is to build the `data.frame` without observing factors. For example, if you are using `read.table` or the like, you can use the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, which will ensure that all strings are read in as `characters`.

I personally set `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` in my .Rprofile because it typically causes me pain, but this isn't best practice (especially when working in a team) because it can lead to inconsistencies in script behaviour.