# R data frames—shifting cell values into NA cells

Tags: r

I'm trying to manipulate some data frames using R, and I keep hitting a roadblock. I began with a data frame `femaleDF` with three columns: Product Name, Person.1, Person.2.

The data frame had values in rows like:

`'E0001', 'John Smith-M', 'Jane Smith-F'`

What I want is to separate the genders into two different data frames. I was able to strip out males from the female list using `grepl` searches for `'-M'`, so now I have something like:

`'E0001', NA, 'Jane Smith-F'`

But now I want to shift the female values from Person.2 into Person.1 if Person.1 == `NA`. Here's what I have so far:

```
female.strip <- function(femaleDF) {     
increment <- 1
repeat {
  if(is.na(femaleDF$Person.1[increment])==TRUE) {
    femaleDF$Person.1[increment] <- femaleDF$Person.2[increment]
    femaleDF$Person.2[increment] <- NA
    increment <- increment + 1
 } else {increment <- increment + 1}
if(increment > nrow(femaleDF)){
    break
    }
 }
}
femaleDF <- female.strip(femaleDF)
```

I think I'm going wrong somewhere in the line where I try to reassign values: `femaleDF$Person.1[increment] <- femaleDF$Person.2[increment]`

I get errors that look like

 `1: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, increment, value = structure(c(282L,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

I'm sure if I knew more about R basics this would be a breeze, but can anyone help me out? Thanks!

**edit:** [not the same as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/invalid-factor-level-na-generated). I didn't create the data frame, I imported it with `read.csv`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid factor level, NA generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/invalid-factor-level-na-generated)

Comment: You can use the `stringsAsFactors=F` argument, as the linked answer suggests, in your `read.csv` call.

Comment: I tried using `read.csv` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, and it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved it, but I'm totally lost as to how and why I solved it. The following code works:

```
female.strip <- function(femaleDF) {     
 increment <- 1
 repeat {
  if(is.na(femaleDF$Person.1[increment])==TRUE){
   femaleDF$Person.1[increment] <- femaleDF$Person.2[increment]
   femaleDF$Person.2[increment] <- NA
   }
  increment <- increment + 1
  if(increment > nrow(femaleDF)){
   break
   }
 }
 return(femaleDF)
}
```

I feel dumb that I forgot to `return` my data frame.