# Why is this not replacing the columns correctly? df1[i, b] <- df2[i, b]

Tags: r

So I have a large dataframe, let's call it df1. Now, I want to replace a subset of rows and columns with values from another dataframe which has exactly the same column names and ids. But the below code isn't producing the results I want and I don't understand why.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:4), a = c("a", "a", "a", "a"), b = c("b", "b", "b", "b"), c = c("c", "c", "c", "c"), d = c("d", "d", "d", "d"))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(2,3), b = c("x", "x"), c = c("y", "y"))

df1[df2$id, names(df2)] <- df2
```

I've looked at `replace` but don't know how to use it with two data frames. I'm looking for something like `merge` which replaces the values.

Comment: When you create your 2 dataframes, add `data.frame(..,stringsAsFactors=F)` so that your columns are not factors. Otherwise, you wont be able to add values that are not part of the factor levels.

Comment: `the below code isn't producing the results I want` this is not helpful. did you get an error or warning? what did it say, did you google it? I get a warning and googling it points to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/invalid-factor-level-na-generated

Comment: The problem is that I'm not getting any errors, it does the replacement but it's incorrect and I don't know how it mixes up the values. I only see that a value on say b at row 2,3 in df1 isn't ("x", "x").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different factor levels in the two data frames. This should work for you:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:4), a = c("a", "a", "a", "a"), b = c("b", "b", "b", "b"), c = c("c", "c", "c", "c"), d = c("d", "d", "d", "d"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(2,3), b = c("x", "x"), c = c("y", "y"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1[df2$id, names(df2)] <- df2
```

Comment: OK, it was the factor problem. Had to add `stringsAsFactor` in the `read.csv` command. Thanks!