# How to replace all NA in a dataframe using tidyr::replace_na?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to fill all NAs in my data with 0's. Does anyone know how to do that using replace_na from tidyr? From documentation, we can easily replace NA's in different columns with different values. But how to replace all of them with some value? I have many columns...

Using mtcars dataset as an example:

```
mtcars [sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 4), sample(1:ncol(mtcars), 4)]<- NA
mtcars %>% replace_na( ??? )
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all the NA by the same values ?

Comment: `mtcars %>% mutate_all(coalesce, 0)`

Answer (score 157):

If replace_na is not a mandatory requirement, following code will work:

```
mtcars %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Reference Issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574804/8382207

Comment: thanks. That works. Is that possible with replace_na? just curious. @Sagar

Comment: Doesn't work, it tells me `Error in eval(ei, envir) : object '.' not found`

Comment: @robertspierre it might be because you are using the new pipe which doesn't have a placeholder. See https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/

Answer (score 93):

I found a way to get it working with `replace_na` as requested (as it is the fastest option via microbenchmark testing):

## UPDATE with `dplyr v1.0.0`

This has been made much easier with addition of the `dplyr::across` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 0))
  )

# Or if you're pipe shy:
mutate(mtcars, across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 0)))
```

That's it! Pretty simple stuff.

## For `dplyr < v1.0.0`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# First, create a list of all column names and set to 0
myList <- setNames(lapply(vector("list", ncol(mtcars)), function(x) x <- 0), names(mtcars))

# Now use that list in tidyr::replace_na 
mtcars %>% replace_na(myList)
```

To apply this to your working data frame, be sure to replace the 2 instances of `mtcars` with whatever you have named your working data frame when creating the `myList` object.

Comment: You can also use a dot to represent the data frame and use the list within a pipe. `mtcars %>% replace_na(setNames(lapply(vector("list", ncol(.)), function(x) x <- 0), names(.)))`

Comment: df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), replace_na, 0)
  )

Comment: It took me a while to find this notation '.x'. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mtcars
mydata[sample(1:nrow(mydata), 4), sample(1:ncol(mydata), 4)]<- NA
mydata %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

Comment: Would love to hear feedback on why this merits downvotes.

Comment: You seem to lose the row names...