# Replace NA with Zero in dplyr without using list()

Tags: r, dplyr, na

In dplyr I can replace NA with 0 using the following code. The issue is this inserts a list into my data frame which screws up further analysis down the line. I don't even understand lists or atomic vectors or any of that at this point. I just want to pick certain columns, and replace all occurrences of NA with zero. And maintain the columns integer status.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"), z = list(1:5, NULL, 10:20))
df
df %>% replace_na(list(x = 0, y = "unknown"))
```

That works but transforms the column into a list. How do I do it without transforming the column into a list?

And here's how to do it in base R. But not sure how to work this into a mutate statement:

```
df$x[is.na(df$x)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What version of `dplyr` are you using? It might be an old one. The `replace_na` function now seems to be in `tidyr`. This works

```
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble::tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"), z = list(1:5, NULL, 10:20))
df %>% replace_na(list(x = 0, y = "unknown")) %>% str()
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: num  1 2 0
#  $ y: chr  "a" "unknown" "b"
#  $ z:List of 3
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : int  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
```

We can see the NA values have been replaced and the columns `x` and `y` are still atomic vectors. Tested with `tidyr_0.7.2`.

Comment: If x is kept in a variable, e.g. col_name, how should the last command be modified?

Answer (score 125):

To replace all NAs in a dataframe use

`df %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)`

Comment: How can we do it with the new pipe ( |> )and placeholder ( _ )?

Comment: Hi @RxT I had the same question and spent some time trying to find the solution. I have posted it as an alternative answer for all future searching people  :-)

Comment: It looks nice and simple, but ````Error: ! Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data. ℹ Error occurred for column `ESVD2.0_Ecozone_Code`. ✖ Can't convert <double> to <character>.````

Comment: It looks nice and simple, but ````Error: ! Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data. ℹ Error occurred for column `ESVD2.0_Ecozone_Code`. ✖ Can't convert <double> to <character>.````

Comment: @MsGISRocker if your column is a character data type you'll prob need to use "0" instead of just 0.

Answer (score 45):

```
dt  <- mutate(dt, x = ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Native Pipe Solution `|>`

I came across this question successfully using [Oliver Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4199944/oliver-oliver)s solution with the magrittr pipe `%>%`

Since his answer the native R pipe `|>` was introduced which doesn't work this way since it doesn't let you access the piped object with the `.`

A solution based on `replace` with the native pipe looks like

```r
df |> {\(.) {replace(.,is.na(.),0)}}()
```

---

To further elaborate the answer and the syntax used we are shortening the call by using an anonymous function which would look like this if we would explicitly define it.

```r
my_replace <- function(x){
  return(replace(
    x = x,
    list = is.na(x),
    values = 0))
}
  
df |> 
  my_replace()

# readable answer without defining it first
df |> {function(x) {replace(
  x=x,
  list=is.na(x),
  values = 0)}}()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of `.xlsx`, I placed an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/warning-message-in-invalid-factor-level-na-generated/62326833#62326833).

```
#install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)
extracted_df <- read.xlsx("test.xlsx", sheetName='Sheet1', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Replace all NAs in a data frame with "G" character
extracted_df[is.na(extracted_df)] <- "G"
```