# How to overwrite a variable in R based on a grep

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple data frame:

```
> var_body_part <- c("eye and nose", "eye", "eye and ear", "eye and mouth", "foot", "foot", "ear", "ear", "foot", "mouth")

> var2 <- c("bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla")

> temp_df <- data.frame(var_body_part, var2)
```

So my data is:

```
> temp_df
   var_body_part var2
1   eye and nose  bla
2            eye  bla
3    eye and ear  bla
4  eye and mouth  bla
5           foot  bla
6           foot  bla
7            ear  bla
8            ear  bla
9           foot  bla
10         mouth  bla
```

Each time I find "eye" I want to replace the row  with HEAD
i.e. (see first 4 lines)

```
   var_body_part var2
1           HEAD  bla
2           HEAD  bla
3           HEAD  bla
4           HEAD  bla
5           foot  bla
6           foot  bla
7            ear  bla
8            ear  bla
9           foot  bla
10         mouth  bla
```

It should be easy...
I select the rows that are affected by the transformation with

```
temp_df$var_body_part[grep("eye", temp_df$var_body_part) ]
```

however  I cannot find the correct statement to replace them with the correct value "HEAD".

So far with my attempts I get a lot of

```
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: More info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/warning-message-in-invalid-factor-level-na-generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue actually is that the columns got converted to `factor` when creating the temp_df. Just use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and you are good to go:

```
temp_df <- data.frame(var_body_part, var2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
temp_df$var_body_part[grep("eye", temp_df$var_body_part)] <- "HEAD"
```

If you want to use factors, you can add "HEAD" to the levels of `var_body_part`:

```
temp_df <- data.frame(var_body_part, var2, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
levels(temp_df$var_body_part) <- c(levels(temp_df$var_body_part), "HEAD")
temp_df$var_body_part[grep("eye", temp_df$var_body_part)] <- "HEAD"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` together with `sub`:

```
transform(temp_df, var_body_part = sub(".*eye.*", "HEAD", var_body_part))
```

The result:

```
   var_body_part var2
1           HEAD  bla
2           HEAD  bla
3           HEAD  bla
4           HEAD  bla
5           foot  bla
6           foot  bla
7            ear  bla
8            ear  bla
9           foot  bla
10         mouth  bla
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward using `gsub()`:

```
mutate_at(temp_df, 'var_body_part', funs(gsub('.*eye.*', 'HEAD', .)))
```