# Replace values by a character in a dataset column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace the 1-values in a dataset column by a character. I tried with

```
dataset$out[dataset$out==1]<-'A'
```

but I obtain the warning message:

```
Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, dataset$out == 1, value = c(1L, 1L,  :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: I think a similar problem solution can be found [Warning message: In `…` : invalid factor level, NA generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/warning-message-in-invalid-factor-level-na-generated)

Comment: Cast `dataset$out` from `factor` to `character` with `dataset$out <- as.character(dataset$out)` before you assign `A` to it. Or bring `A` to the levels of `dataset$out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the comments above have pointed out, your column "out" is a factor, try str(dataset$out). In factors, you have levels which are predefined values, and they are used for many purposes.

For example:

```
x = LETTERS[1:5]
x = x[-1]
table(x[-1])

x = factor(LETTERS[1:5])
levels(x)
x = x[-1]
levels(x)
table(x[-1])
```

In the example above, even if you remove 'A' from the vector `x`, because the levels are predefined, it shows you it is missing 'A' when you table it.

So you cannot replace an element in a factor column, with something that doesn't exist in the levels.

```
x = factor(LETTERS[1:5])
# ok
x[1] = "E"
# not ok
x[1] = "F"
```

So for your data, do:

```
dataset <- data.frame(id=1:5,out=c('1',LETTERS[2:5]))
dataset

  id out
1  1   1
2  2   B
3  3   C
4  4   D
5  5   E

dataset$out <- with(dataset,replace(as.character(out),out=='1','A'))
dataset

  id out
1  1   A
2  2   B
3  3   C
4  4   D
5  5   E

dataset$out <- factor(dataset$out)
```

In the above, I am converting them to a character first, then replacing those that are '1' with 'A'. You can convert them back to factor afterwards, if need be.